# Android: View.setID(int id) programmatically - how to avoid ID conflicts?

Tags: android, android-view, conflict

I'm adding TextViews programmatically in a for-loop and add them to an ArrayList.

How do I use `TextView.setId(int id)`? What Integer ID do I come up with so it doesn't conflict with other IDs?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

According to `View` documentation

> The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number.

So you can use any positive integer you like, but in this case there can be some views with equivalent id's. If you want to search for some view in hierarchy calling to `setTag` with some key objects may be handy.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware that IDs need not be unique? So does `findViewById` make any  guarantees then as to which view is returned if there's more than one with the same ID? The docs don't mention anything.

Comment: I think the docs mention something about this. If you have views with the same ID in the same hierarchy then `findViewById` will return the first it finds.

Comment: @kaneda i don't think it gets the first id. it gets the id that's in the layout that you set in setContentView()

Comment: @DanyY I'm not quite sure if I am understanding correctly what you mean. What I tried to say was that if the layout you set with `setContentView()` has let's say, 10 views with their id set to the same id number in the **same hierarchy**, then a call to `findViewById([repeated_id])` would return the first view set with that one repeated id. That's what I meant.

Comment: -1 I don't agree with this answer because onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState need a unique id to be able to save/restore the state of the view hierarchy. If two views have the same id, the state of one of them will be lost. So unless you save the View state all yourself having duplicate ids isn't a good idea.

Comment: The **Id should be unique**. Starting from **API level 17** there is a static method in the View class that generates a random Id to use it as view id. 

That method ensures that the generated id will not collide with any other view id already generated by the aapt tool during the build time.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#generateViewId%28%29

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin The quoted documentation from Google tells you it's true. :) A very common example of this is a `RecyclerView`. If your adapter represents every item with the same layout, any ID in that layout will be repeated once for every instance of the view currently in the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 681):

From API level 17 and above, you can call: [View.generateViewId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29)

Then use [View.setId(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)).

If your app is targeted lower than API level 17, use [ViewCompat.generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ViewCompat#generateviewid)

Comment: I put it in my source code because we want to support lower API levels. It is working but the infinite loop is not a good practice.

Comment: @SimonXinCheng Infinite loops is a common pattern used in non blocking algorithms. For example have a look at `AtomicInteger` methods implementation.

Comment: Works great! One note: based on my experiments, you must call setId() BEFORE you add the view to an existing layout, or else OnClickListener  won't work properly.

Comment: Thank you would be too small but THANK YOU. Question, what is `for(;;)` I've never seen that before. What is that called?

Comment: What if I want to access to a specific view later? How would I know the id? Let's say the 10th out of 50 generated views?

Comment: Make sure you increment the number in AtomicInteger for each view you generate with this, otherwise they'll all be 1 and you'll be banging your head for a while trying to figure out why it's not working :)

Comment: @Aggressor : Its an empty 'for' loop.

Comment: Are these id's registered into R.java?

Comment: You should've placed ```if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {``` inside `generateViewId()` because this code will work correctly only with the boilerplate code around it

Comment: I disagree. This is only for below 17 where there's no google implementation on generateViewId(). Everywhere else, you should be using Google's.

Comment: ViewCompat also has this method for api lower than 17

Comment: This should be the answer!

Answer (score 189):

You can define the ID's you'll use later in `R.id` class using an xml resource file, and let Android SDK set the actual unique values during compile time.

```
 res/values/ids.xml
```

```
<item name="my_edit_text_1" type="id"/>
<item name="my_button_1" type="id"/>
<item name="my_time_picker_1" type="id"/>
```

To use it in the code:

```
myEditTextView.setId(R.id.my_edit_text_1);
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I have an unknown number of elements I'll be assigning ids to.

Comment: @MooingDuck I know this is a year late, but when I have to assign unique Ids at runtime with an unknown number of elements, I simply use `"int currentId = 1000; whateverView.setId(currentId++);` - That increments the ID every time `currentId++` is used, ensuring a unique ID, and I can store the IDs in my ArrayList for later access.

Comment: @MikeinSAT: That only guarantees that they're unique amongst themselves. That doesn't make it "so it doesn't conflict with other IDs", which is a key part of the question.

Comment: This is the winning answer because others were giving Android Studio's code analysis tool a s--- fit, and because I need an ID that tests know without adding yet another variable. But add `<resources>`.

Comment: @Windgate You need to learn to find and use Android documentation. Both setId() and generateViewId() are methods for View and so are inherited by LinearLayout. Here's one link to get you started. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setId(int)  You should have been able to find it in a few seconds using a good search engine and the search term "android view setid". Might not be the top result but it should be high up.

Comment: @Smartybartfast setId() or generateViewId() are static methods of View class, not methods of a View object, that was my problem when trying to code. I'm programming with Xamarin (C#) instead of Java and I had a mess with caps when reading this post. I deleted my last comment and vote up this solution, it works fine, thanks for the help and thanks for remember my last comment was wrong

Answer (score 62):

Also you can define `ids.xml` in `res/values`. You can see an exact example in android's sample code.

```
samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/RadioGroup1.java
samples/ApiDemp/res/values/ids.xml
```

Comment: Here is also an answer with this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216294/android-programatically-add-id-to-r-id

Comment: For reference, I found the file in:
/samples/android-15/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/RadioGroup1.java

Answer (score 32):

Since API 17, the `View` class has a [static method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29) `generateViewId()` that will

> generate a value suitable for use in setId(int)

Answer (score 25):

Edit: As commented by other users this approach is bad for performance, there are new ways to achieve this.

This works for me:

```
static int id = 1;

// Returns a valid id that isn't in use
public int findId(){  
    View v = findViewById(id);  
    while (v != null){  
        v = findViewById(++id);  
    }  
    return id++;  
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6790714/581205) is a bit more complicated but I'd bet it'll work. Using global variables in multithreaded environment will surely fail some day, especially with multiple cores.

Comment: Also, isn't this possibly slow for complicated layouts?

Comment: ```findViewById()``` is a slow operation. The approach works, but at the cost of performance.

Comment: so you can use random int instead of looping

Answer (score 11):

(This was a comment to dilettante's answer but it got too long...hehe)

Of course a static is not needed here.  You could use SharedPreferences to save, instead of static. Either way, the reason is to save the current progress so that its not too slow for complicated layouts. Because, in fact, after its used once, it will be rather fast later. However, I dont feel this is a good way to do it because if you have to rebuild your screen again (say `onCreate` gets called again), then you probably want to start over from the beginning anyhow, eliminating the need for static. Therefore, just make it an instance variable instead of static.

Here is a smaller version that runs a bit faster and might be easier to read:

```
int fID = 0;

public int findUnusedId() {
    while( findViewById(++fID) != null );
    return fID;
}
```

This above function should be sufficient. Because, as far as I can tell, android-generated IDs are in the billions, so this will probably return `1` the first time and always be quite fast.
Because, it wont actually be looping past the used IDs to find an unused one. However, the loop *is* there should it actually find a used ID.

However, if you still want the progress saved between subsequent recreations of your app, and want to avoid using static. Here is the SharedPreferences version:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE);

public int findUnusedId() {
    int fID = sp.getInt("find_unused_id", 0);
    while( findViewById(++fID) != null );
    SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit();
    spe.putInt("find_unused_id", fID);
    spe.commit();
    return fID;
}
```

This answer to a similar question should tell you everything you need to know about IDs with android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13241629/693927

EDIT/FIX: Just realized I totally goofed up the save. I must have been drunk.

Comment: This should be the top answer. Great use of ++ keyword and empty statements ;)

Answer (score 11):

The 'Compat' library now also supports the `generateViewId()` method for API levels prior 17.

Just make sure to use a version of the `Compat` library that is `27.1.0+`

For example, in your `build.gradle` file, put :

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`

Then you can simply use the `generateViewId()` from the `ViewCompat` class instead of the `View` class as follow:

`//Will assign a unique ID
myView.id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()`

Happy coding !

Answer (score 6):

Just an addition to the answer of @phantomlimb,

while `View.generateViewId()` require API Level >= 17,
this tool is compatibe with all API.

according to current API Level,
it decide weather using system API or not.

so you can use `ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId()` and `View.generateViewId()` in the
same time and don't worry about getting same id

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * {@link View#generateViewId()}要求API Level >= 17,而本工具类可兼容所有API Level
 * <p>
 * 自动判断当前API Level,并优先调用{@link View#generateViewId()},即使本工具类与{@link View#generateViewId()}
 * 混用,也能保证生成的Id唯一
 * <p>
 * =============
 * <p>
 * while {@link View#generateViewId()} require API Level >= 17, this tool is compatibe with all API.
 * <p>
 * according to current API Level, it decide weather using system API or not.<br>
 * so you can use {@link ViewIdGenerator#generateViewId()} and {@link View#generateViewId()} in the
 * same time and don't worry about getting same id
 * 
 * @author fantouchx@gmail.com
 */
public class ViewIdGenerator {
    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int generateViewId() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
            for (;;) {
                final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
                // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
                int newValue = result + 1;
                if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF)
                    newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
                if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return View.generateViewId();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @kenyee the code snippet `for (;;) { … }` comes from the Android Source Code.

Comment: My understanding is all generated IDs occupy the number space 0x01000000–0xffffffff, so you're guaranteed a non-clash, but I can't remember where I read this.

Comment: How to reset ..`generateViewId()`

Comment: @kenyee has a point, it can collide with ids generated within View class. See my answer :)

Comment: `else { return View.generateViewId(); }` this will going to infinite loop for api level smaller than 17 devices ?

Answer (score 5):

In order to dynamically generate View Id  form API 17 use

[generateViewId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29)

Which will generate a value suitable for use in `setId(int)`. This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for `R.id`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int fID;
do {
    fID = Tools.generateViewId();
} while (findViewById(fID) != null);
view.setId(fID);
```

...

```
public class Tools {
    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);
    public static int generateViewId() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
            for (;;) {
                final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
                int newValue = result + 1;
                if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF)
                    newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
                if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return View.generateViewId();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String TAG() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
}

private AtomicInteger lastFldId = null;

public int generateViewId(){

    if(lastFldId == null) {
        int maxFld = 0;
        String fldName = "";
        Field[] flds = R.id.class.getDeclaredFields();
        R.id inst = new R.id();

        for (int i = 0; i < flds.length; i++) {
            Field fld = flds[i];

            try {
                int value = fld.getInt(inst);

                if (value > maxFld) {
                    maxFld = value;
                    fldName = fld.getName();
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e(TAG(), "error getting value for \'"+ fld.getName() + "\' " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG(), "maxId="+maxFld +"  name="+fldName);
        lastFldId = new AtomicInteger(maxFld);
    }

    return lastFldId.addAndGet(1);
}
```

Comment: Please add a proper description to your answer in a way that's clearer to future visitors to assess the value of your answer. Code-only answers are frowned upon and can be deleted during reviews. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

inspired by @dilettante answer, here's my solution as an extension function in kotlin:

```
/* sets a valid id that isn't in use */
fun View.findAndSetFirstValidId() {
    var i: Int
    do {
        i = Random.nextInt()
    } while (findViewById<View>(i) != null)
    id = i
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My Choice:

```
// Method that could us an unique id

    int getUniqueId(){
        return (int)    
                SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();    
    }
```