# How to specify id when uses include in layout xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout xml file, I have included other layout xml file (each
with a different android id).

```
<include layout="@layout/view_contact_name" android:id="+id/test1"/>
<include layout="@layout/view_contact_name" android:id="+id/test2"/>
```

But when I run it in the emulator, and start Hierarchy Viewer, each of
the layout still shows 'NO_ID', and in my code, I have
`findViewById(R.id.test1)` and `findViewById(R.id.test2)` both returns null.

Can anyone please help me with my problem ?

Comment: Your IDs are missing the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 313):

Specify the ID in the `<include>`

```
<include layout="@layout/test" android:id="@+id/test1" />
```

Then use two `findViewById` to access fields in the layout

```
View test1View = findViewById(R.id.test1);
TextView test1TextView = (TextView) test1View.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Using that approach, you can access any field in any include you have.

Comment: This method return me null value for test1View object.

Comment: I don't really see the difference, can you explain?

Comment: I found out that if the layout that us included is using merge, this will not help. But in case where merge is not used, this works.

Comment: @Zlatko Yep, and this can't work with `merge` even in theory, because the result of including a `merge` is not a single view, but a bunch of them. So it's OK.

Comment: So is there anything to do in the case that <merge> is included?

Comment: This will only work in case merge is not used. In case of merge it is not possible as specified here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36918#c3

Answer (score 66):

I found out, that if you are using `<merge>` tag in your include layout, then the ID of include transfers to the merge tag which is not real view.

So either remove merge, or replace it with some layout.

Tor Norbye [wrote](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36918#c3):

> The `<include>` tag is not a real view, so findByView will not find it. The @id attribute (and any other attributes you've set on the include tag) gets applied on the root tag of the included layout instead. So your activity.getView(R.id.included1) should in fact be the `<TextView>` itself.

Comment: Good one. I remove merge tag and it start working but my question here is what is the usage of merge tag if any include layout working without it?

Answer (score 44):

Romain Guy [indicates](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) that you can override the ID of an included layout by putting an `android:id` attribute inside the `<include>` tag.

```
<include android:id="@+id/cell1" layout="@layout/workspace_screen" />
```

Comment: This is correct. The way to reference the root element in the included layout file is by the id given in the 'include' tag (unless it is not given).

Comment: ID in <include> = root's ID in included layout

Comment: It appears to me if I set the id first (in include tag, it overrides the id from the included layout, right?), I will have the include tag to be initially '@+id/cell1' and then the layout='@layout/workspace_screen' will override the android:id again with the id of the included layout. @Ron Romero's answers makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 22):

I think the top answer misses the most important point and might mislead people into thinking the `<include/>` tag creates a View that holds the include contents.

The key point is that include's **id** is *passed* to the root view of the include's layout file.

Meaning that this:

```
// activity_main.xml
<include layout="@layout/somelayout" android:id="@+id/someid"/>

// somelayout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Becomes this:

```
// activity_main.xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/someid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: it is true. that makes me more clear. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

yes is like this, but careful when the layout inserted in include field is a custom one and you want to access that root layout. That  layout in this case @layout/test  test, is actually returned in first line.

```
test test1View = (test)findViewById(R.id.test1);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. you must set id each include tag
2. included child element set a
       new id. if you look how to generate new id, look at this entry:
       https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442898/1136117

Answer (score 2):

Problem is we try to use id which is not declared in current layout file. 
Instead of declaring again, id can be simply referred using `@+id/`. If you refactor original id name through Android Studio it does refactor in included layout as well.

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"**
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In a case of using `<RecyclerView>` find the id of `<include>` by using an instance of inflated view or else it will return **null**.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            View include_1 = view.findViewById(R.id.include_1);
            mTextView = (TextView) include_1.findViewById(R.id.text_id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have set id to either root tag of included layout then you can use that id 
or you can set id to included layout.

But you can not set id to both it may throw exception.

```
<include layout="@layout/view_contact_name" android:id="+id/test1"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

....
</LinearLayout>
```

Or

```
<include layout="@layout/view_contact_name"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBottomMainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

....
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When talking about include you either have an id on the root view inside the included layout file or on the include line itself and not on both. For example:

```
<include layout="@layout/layout1" android:id="@+id/layout1"/>
```

### Layout 1 file

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout2">

</RelativeLayout>
```

The above example is wrong because technically you have two id's declared for the same layout. So what you have to do is pick which element will have the id.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the `id` when you are including a xml file is like setting it to any   *xml element*

**Example:**

```
*list_layout.xml*
`<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvNames"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>`


*activity_main.xml*
`<RelativeLayout
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

      <include
          layout="@layout/list_layout"
          android:id="@+id/myList" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Now if you want to get that to use in `.kt file`, just use normally `findViewById`

**Exemplo**

```
*MainActivity.kt*

`val myList: RecycleView = findViewById(R.id.myList)`
```

Answer (score -2):

Wow, I can't believe this question doesn't have the right answer yet. It's simple  tags suck. You can only change things that start with `android:layout_` which `android:id` doesn't match. So the answer is you can't. Sorry. What you can do instead is create a class that will be a ViewGroup which will inflate the included views inside, then add that as a tag in your layout, but that's about it.