# view not found for fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using four xml files.When I try to start a fragment i get no view found errorI am using four xml files and am having a mainactivity with navigation bar i want to start a fragment when a option is clciked from navigation bar but when i clcik an item i get no view found for tab1 fragment

```
    **activity main xml**
            <
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



    <
    android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />




    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



    This is number 2 App main bar.xml


Code:


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>





    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    This is Number 3 content main.xml


    Code:


    <
    FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    This is number 4 nav header

    Code:


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:src="@drawable/logo192"
            />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EDX Engine Option" />



    This is the mainactivity








    package com.example.sabarinathan.navigationdrawer;


    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.Sample) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sample",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                Tab1 fragment = new Tab1();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_frame_layout, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            } else if (id == R.id.EnterProfile) {

            } else if (id == R.id.RequestUniv) {

            } else if (id == R.id.ViewSuggestions) {

            }
            else if(id== R.id.Home){

            }
            else if(id== R.id.AdiitionalApps){

            }
            else if(id== R.id.Coupon){

            }
            else if(id== R.id.FAQ){

            }
            else if(id== R.id.FlashHelp){

            }
            else if(id== R.id.Premium){

            }
            else if(id== R.id.ABoutUs){

            }

            else if(id== R.id.Tab1){


            }
            else if(id== R.id.Tab2){

            }
            else if(id== R.id.Tab3){

            }
            else if(id== R.id.Tab4){

            }
            else if(id== R.id.Tab5){

            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    }

    This is the fragment class


package com.example.sabarinathan.navigationdrawer;
// This project was created by Ferdousur Rahman Shajib
// www.androstock.com
// You use this project anytime, anywhere. There is no copywrite issue.

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * Created by Ferdousur Rahman Shajib on 27-10-2015.
 */
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    Activity activity;
    Button button1;
    private WebView webView;
    private Bundle webViewBundle;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,
                container, false);
        activity = getActivity();
        webView = (WebView) ll.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        if (webViewBundle == null) {
            webView.loadUrl("https://edxengine.com/services/MyUniversity/");
        } else {
            webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
        }
        return ll;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }




}

This the fragment xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>


when i start a fragment i get no view found error
```

Comment: There is a lot of answers for this question. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803672/findviewbyid-not-working-for-an-include) one of them

Answer (score 0):

Use getSupportFragmentManager() istead of getFragmentManager().