# Include in Android: findViewById returns null

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

I have some app. 
I wrote and tested it on Android 5.1. When I tried to run my app on Android 6.0 I've got the exception. The exception appeare after I try to bind a FloatingActionButton and set OnClickListener because of null. FindViewById returns null when I try to get it with FrameLayout from "include" directive.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context instance;

    private MainPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    public ViewPager mViewPager;

    FloatingActionButton fab;
    FloatingActionButton fab_settings;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(fabOnClick);

        fab_settings = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_settings); // <---- Returns null

        fab_settings.setOnClickListener(setsOnClick); // <---- Exception
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vjs.classesschedule.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/color_title">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_title4" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:visibility="gone">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tab" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <include layout="@layout/fab_layout" android:id="@+id/fab_frame"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fab_layout.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/fab_frame">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_dic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_assignment_white_24dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

When I use SDK >= 23 I have the exception and if SDK < 23 it's OK.
How can I solve it?

**UPDATE:**

In `activity_main.xml` I changed from:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
    app:fabSize="mini" />
```

to:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
        app:fabSize="mini" />
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
        app:fabSize="mini" />
```

After it `fab_settings` is still null. I don't understand why!

Comment: Can you edit your answer and paste log from logcat with error

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that the error is coming from the viewPager and the tabLayout. Both of which aren't declared in your layout files. Please paste the logs from logcat.

Comment: Have you tried setting FrameLayout's height to `"wrap_content"`? Or it has to be `"match_parent"`?

Comment: Updated `activity_main.xml`

Comment: `"wrap_content"` or `"match_parent"` it doesn't matter - returns null.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. My last idea is to [debug the layout](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html).

Comment: @VJS  Do you see both of your FABs on the screen? I think that one is hiding the other one, and that's why you're getting null.

Comment: `fab` exists and is visible. `fab_settings` is hidden and shows with animation. On Android 5.1 it works, on 6.0 does not work.

Comment: I set visible `fab_settings`  and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

It was my mistake. I didn't notice the new folder `layout-v23` where the activity was exist. My problem was solved after deleting `layout-v23`.

Thank all of you.

Answer (score 0):

First find framelayout with fab_frame id. Second framelayout.findviewbyid(your fab id)
Check this question [findViewById not working for an include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803672/findviewbyid-not-working-for-an-include)

Comment: I tryed, it's not working too. 
`
fab_layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fab_frame); 
fab_settings = (FloatingActionButton) fab_layout.findViewById(R.id.fab_settings);
`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared "fabOnClick" & "setsOnClick". Declare them, hopefully it will solve the problem.

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(fabOnClick);

            fab_settings = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_settings); // 

            fab_settings.setOnClickListener(setsOnClick); // <---- Exception
```

Comment: He said: "*FindViewById returns null when I try to get it with FrameLayout from "include" directive*". `fabOnClick` and `setsOnClick` are not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
View frame = findViewById(R.id.fab_frame);

fab_settings = frame.findViewById(R.id.fab_settings);
fab_settings.setOnClickListener(setsOnClick);
```

Comment: _frame_ is null.

Comment: This solution should work, if not then you should thoroughly check for other issues

Comment: Which issues can be?

Comment: Try removing id from include

Comment: I commented it.

    <!--<include layout="@layout/fab_layout" android:id="@+id/fab_frame"/>-->

Answer (score -1):

You can write something like this for FloatingActionButton for the setOnClickListerner method.

```
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Write here anything that you wish to do on click of FAB
}
});
```

Comment: that wasn't the question/problem