# findViewById for view inside an included merge root-element

Tags: java, android, merge, include, findviewbyid

I want to use a view in multiple activities. In my case it's a FloatingActionButton. The moment I am searching for the view via findViewById the program throws a *NullPointerException*. How do I get access to the FloatingActionButton?

---

As the button should always be the same, I created a XML Layout only including the FloatingActionButton inside a `merge`root element to reduce overhead when using `ìnclude`.

> floating_button.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/include_merge" >

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addBloodDonation"/>

</merge>
```

To use this in my other XML Layouts I use the `include` tag

> XML Activitiy Layouts that should `include` the FloatingActionButton

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include_merge"
    layout="@layout/floating_button" />
```

That works so far.

To have the same functionality in all my Activities, I created a BaseActivity which my other classes inherit from, e.g. my MainActivity.

> BaseActivity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View include_merge = findViewById(R.id.include_merge);
        fab = include_merge.findViewById(R.id.addBloodDonation);
    }
}
```

> MainActivity (exemplarily)

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

When starting the application I receive a *NullPointerException* in BaseActivity for trying to find the inner element as the View variable *include_merge* is null.

As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803672/findviewbyid-not-working-for-an-include#10803746) the `include` tag and the root element should have the same `android:id`. Is there a difference when using a `merge` as root element? And is it even possible to convert a `merge` tag into a View.

<del>Do I need to make use of setContentView in the BaseActivity as its onCreate method is called before the one of MainActivity?</del>

---

### Edit:

Added `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to BaseActivity as mentioned in the comments which still does not fix it.

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` not get called yet . And your `BaseActivity's` `onCreate()` getting called first .

Comment: Adding `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` in BaseActivity after calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` does not fix it. I tried it as I already assumed something like that before. Anyway, I can update my Question so that it is including this call.

Comment: It's still trying to find the view before calling `setContentView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set an `id` to the `<include>` or `<merge>` tag. Just remove it as well as `findViewById(R.id.include_merge)`. The `<merge>` tag indicates that all its views are added to the container of the `<include>` tag. Thus there's no `View` with the id you've set to it. But you can directly find the FAB.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fab = include_merge.findViewById(R.id.addBloodDonation);
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for helping :)