# Initializing View in fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Ok so my problem is that I have included a layout in my fragment view using `<include.../>` tag but whenever I try to initialize it throws a null pointer exception error

```
<include layout="@layout/pro_ocr" />
```

I tried a couple of methods to findViewById() like:

```
v.findViewById(R.id.crossProOCR);
getActivity.findViewById(R.id.crossProOCR);
```

but it didnt work a solution would be great help now

Comment: is this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803672/findviewbyid-not-working-for-an-include

Comment: Could you put all layout ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are finding the id of the parent layout inside pro_ocr, hence you are getting an NPE.
An `include` is used like any other view inside your layout.
You need to give the include tag an id:

```
 <include
 android:id="@+id/proOcr"
 layout="@layout/pro_ocr" />
```

Then you can use it as `View` in your Fragment.
Getting the ids of the views inside the included layout is similar to any other view.

Comment: I am trying to initialize a view inside a layout that is being included.

Comment: Where are you initializing it? Can you add it to question along with the included xml layout?