# programmatically add id to R.id

Tags: android, android-edittext, unit-testing

I am creating an `EditText` object which I then try to reference in a unit test. What is the best way to add a new `id` to `R.id` for this dynamically created object, so that I can later reference it via `findViewById()` in the unit test?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: View.setID(int id) programmatically - how to avoid ID conflicts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts)

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You can set ID's you'll use later in R.id class using an xml resource file, and let Android SDK give them unique values during compile time.

**res/values/ids.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="my_edit_text_1" type="id"/>
    <item name="my_button_1" type="id"/>
    <item name="my_time_picker_1" type="id"/>

</resources>
```

To use it in code:

```
myEditTextView.setId(R.id.my_edit_text_1);
```

Comment: can i call the file anothername.xml ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yeah, as with all Android resources, you can name that .xml anyway you like...

Answer (score 2):

You can use setId for every view and assign any positive number, based on google developer:

> Sets the identifier for this view. The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number.[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int))

so you can use

```
EveryView.setId(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution as an extension function in kotlin:

```
/* sets a valid id that isn't in use */
fun View.findAndSetFirstValidId() {
    var i: Int
    do {
        i = Random.nextInt()
    } while (findViewById<View>(i) != null)
    id = i
}
```