# Android - Textview added when button pressed

Tags: android, textview

I want to know if it is possible to make a textview load on the screen when a button is pressed...

I do not want to make the textview invisible, then visible when the button is pressed, I want it to actually (dynamically) appear on the screen.

Any help?

Comment: Do you have any code that you are working off of? If so, please post it in your question.

Comment: similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view) about adding view dynamiclaly

Comment: Read my [post][1], this will solve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930604/android-add-textview-to-layout-when-button-is-pressed/6932540#6932540

Answer (score 1):

You have to dynamically add view in a parent view
for that you have to create a view

for example
You have a parent view name `layParent` and you want to add `textview` inside `layParent`
for first make a textview using code like this

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context)
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("textview");
layParent.addView(tv);
```

write this code in button click event so that you can add text-view as many as you click on button

for more information see this question

[Android - Dynamically Add Views into View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)