# Adding views Dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know if its possible to add a view say textview directly from the activity (Dynamically) in android without actually having it in the layout ?

Comment: View my earlier [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930604/android-add-textview-to-layout-when-button-is-pressed/6932540#6932540),I hope it help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your Activity:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setId(42);

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width, height);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
tv.setLayoutParams(params);

setContentView(tv);
```

Where myView is the View you want to add a View to. It can be of any type you want.

Comment: What if its a relative layout that i'm using ? Can i explicitly give the position where i want to add it using the id's like its done in the xml file ?

Comment: And in this case myview is a view that should already be given in the xml because unless and until u do that you wouldnt get an id for it right ? But i want to add a view without defining it in the xml .

Comment: Try my latest edit to add a view programmatically without having it in xml.