# New EditText when button pressed

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a button within a relative layout, and want it to create a new EditText in a different relative layout when pressed (a completely new EditText, not just turning the visibility on/off). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932540/6755360)
answer has helped, however I cannot change it to make it add an EditText instead of adding a new TextView. I don't need it to save the text inside any views or anything, just create another EditText, similar to an add contact button.

Comment: To be clear, you are working in java swings. Right? If yes and by EditText, did you mean JTextField? Sorry I didn't quite understand the question. Btw, if you are working in android then please tag 'android' in your question.

Comment: absolutely you are working on android `Relative layout` , `EditText` and `TextView` are the terms of Android. So, Why not you included android tag ?

Answer (score 1):

```
private EditText createNewEditText() {
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
    Editext.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    return edittext;
}
```

just make new relative in xml file

add this edittext like this

```
rl.addView(createNewEditText());
```