# How can we set id as a number for UI Elements?

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I am quite interested and confused both. Sometimes ago I was working on a project who has already implemented by some one. And after worked on that i found that he was using a unique number for find ID for its UI elements. Just like if we need to find id for `TextView` then we write,

```
 TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

but in that code it was like,

```
 TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(012345678);
```

something like this.I have searched a lot in project also tried out to find that number but i couldn't. In `R.java` file i have also checked but there was also not. Its unique id its generated automatically as usual but i couldn't find a number in whole project.

So my question how can we use like this way? Is this possible??

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(012345678);
```

If this is possible then where we can define that id number and use it for UI elements.

Help will be appreciated!!

Comment: have you try to look for the hex ?

Comment: Yes. But i couldn't figure out because i have checked in whole project but i couldn't found anything at all

Comment: I guess he is just using the values taken out `R.java`. I evaluate this technique as **very poor** and definetely **not suggested**. It's much much better to use the classic way: by name

Comment: @FrankN.Stein No for that i have also checked R.java file and its id was different.

Comment: Different like a hex to decimal conversion?

Comment: Yes it was totally different.

Comment: So he's probably assigning the ids **manually** via `setId()` (awful!!). **The only reason for doing so is that the controls are created programmatically. + The only reason to create controls programmatically is that you have no other chance**

Comment: May be you are right..But for setId() i had searched careful there is not found anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13241629/3049917

Comment: @TopCat Thanks for link. But please don't mind he had never created programmatic ally. I understood from this link but i am not satisfied 100% because of that used code.

Comment: Just as a hint `012345678` is an octivial number ;-)

Comment: check this may be help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

[image]

from folder gen you can find R.java there is a class named id like in image.

for example

```
public static final int action_bar=0x7f06001c;
```

so instead of R.id.action_bar i can use 0x7f06001c.

Comment: Your answer is crap. That file will been overriden when you edit any ressources. There is also a warning at the top of the file: **AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
This class was automatically generated by the
aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
should not be modified by hand.**

Comment: i know that editing autogenerated file makes erorr. in my answer i didn't tell to edit the auto-generated file. i expined how to get integer id.you misunderstood me @rekire

Comment: Well I'm not alone, that is possible indeed but not an good idea.

Comment: ya, its makes difficult to handle @rekire

Answer (score 0):

That is not directly possible as you might think. You can define your own custom ids which are not used in any xml files. I think that is what you want. To do this create a new xml files in `res/values/ids.xml` with this content:

```
<resources>
    <item name="your_custom_id" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Than you can use it as `R.id.your_custom_id` I think that is what you want.

Comment: So for  type can i write 012345678 ??

Comment: i think this should be in res/values/ids.xml http://stackoverflow.com/a/3217786/3049917

Comment: Well that wouldn't be wrong however the filename does not really care AFIK. In the end all value xml files are combined to one file, but you are right so I'll update my answer. @PG_Android no that is a hardcoded marker for the build tools.

Comment: @rekire I have tried but its giving a error in r.java file