# How to retrieve data from view injected programmatically without id

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a scroll view and a linear layout. Depending upon the data i am getting i generate a view respectively and inject it to the main layout.

Now each view contains certain value but no id as they are injected dynamically. How to access the value from each for further processing.
I have tried on click listener but did not get good results.
I want to add one thing these views can vary some are multiple. some are single etc.
 I need your valuable suggestion and will post code if necessary.

Comment: You can give the views an id by calling `setId()`

Comment: @SebastianWalla Is it correct to give id like 1 2 3. will it not conflict. What if i use layout id and some no appended togather as viewId . or what if i use id and tag. What approach should i use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments: `View` has a [setId(int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)) method.
Use that to access your view. Store them in some list, map or write to file system for further usage.
You could also use `SharedPreferences` to pass the information of the views to another intent.

Comment: same doubt about conflicting id issue. Is it correct to give id like 1 2 3. will it not conflict. What if i use layout id and some no appended togather as viewId . or what if i use id and tag. What approach should i use

Comment: It depends on what are you planning to do. Please describe you general task.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `View` Class has a `setId()` method. As all your views inherit from this class, they also have this method. As an id you could specify the views in an xml file before, so you won't have any conflicts with double or more used ids, as [descibed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216294/programatically-add-id-to-r-id).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an API >= 17 you can use the [`generateViewId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29) method if you are worried about id collision.

You may also consider using `setTag()` instead of `setId()` as well.