# How to set different ids' for dynamic buttons programmatically? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a button (add) that creates new buttons when pressed (up to 8). But when I try to refer to these buttons and add functionality, I am unable to find the ids' for them. How could I make and find ids' for these buttons?

Note: the button ids should be created automatically when (add) is pressed.

```
val LLayout: View = layout
    var currentId = 0


    add.setOnClickListener {
        val addedButton = Button(this)
        addedButton.text = written.text.toString()
        addedButton.id = currentId++
        addedButton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        (LLayout as LinearLayout).addView(addedButton)
        //clearing text from EditText written
        written.text.clear()
    }
```

Comment: already asked https://stackoverflow.com/a/3217786/9181430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate an Id for each button using `generateViewId()` method.

```
 addedButton.id = generateViewId()
```

Also, Create a new Button every time the user clicks on add button. So you should do something like this:

```
add.setOnClickListener {
        val addedButton = Button(this)
        addedButton.text = written.text.toString()
        addedButton.id = generateViewId()
        addedButton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        (LLayout as LinearLayout).addView(addedButton)
        //clearing text from EditText written
        written.text.clear()
    }
```

Comment: How can I reference the generated id later on. For example, if I want to make the button lead to a new activity, change color, Etc.

Comment: You can save the generated id or button in an array or list and can reference it later.

Comment: Could you show how to do this in your answer please?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a unique id you can simply set tag property for each `Button` object and then find that button with that `tag` and define your functionality

Answer (score 0):

For unique id you can set the (number of child view + 1) as id to the newly created Button.