# Android PagerAdapter, problems adding manually inflated fragments

Tags: fragment, layout-inflater, fragmentpageradapter

I am using a FragmentPagerAdapter to show several tabs (associted with Fragments) of type MyFrag. Within MyFrag.onCreateView(), I programmatically inflate a couple of internal Fragments: MyInternalF1, and MyInternalF2.

What I get is a awkward display result. The external, MyFrag instances are fine - and are associated with their tabs. But the internal Fragments are embedded inside the wrong fragments... The first MyFrag does contain its own internal Frags, but the 2nd, 3rd, and so forth MyFrags either don't have any internal Frags, or host some other Frament's internal Frags. (The internal fragments work OK, they are just located on random fragments).

I am using the tabs/pager sample widget from the v13 samples:
samples/Support13Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv13/app/FragmentPagerSupport.java

Pseudo code:

```
Class MyFrag extends Fragment
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    ....
    FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    trans.add(R.id.myfragContainer, new MyInternalF1, "InternalF1");
    trans.add(R.id.myfragContainer, new MyInternalF2, "InternalF2");
    trans.commit();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the FragmentTransaction.add() function. It takes, as first parameter the ID of the containing view - containerViewId. You cannot directly pass a view, you must use an ID. Obviously, for inflated views, the id of the container view is THE SAME for all inflated interfaces. Since they all reside in the same activity - the transaction chooses the first view instance it finds. You cannot control it. So when MyFragment calls onCreate(), the internal Fragments may be added to views that do not belong to their parent.

This is a problem in the FragmentTransaction API: it would have been nice if it let you specify an explicit View, rather than just an ID, as the parent view. see: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54051

Anyway, I have a workaround for now. You simply manually modify the container's ID in the onCreate function. Then pass the modified ID to the add() function.
See also: [Programmatic Views how to set unique id's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790623/programmatic-views-how-to-set-unique-ids)  (for generateViewId() function).

```
Class MyFrag extends Fragment
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        ....
        int containerID = generateViewId();
        infView.findViewById(R.id.frag_container).setId(containerID);

        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.add(containerID, new MyInternalF1, "InternalF1");
        trans.add(containerID, new MyInternalF2, "InternalF2");
        trans.commit();
        ....
        return infView;
    }
}
```