# How can I assign an ID to a view programmatically?

Tags: android, android-view, android-resources, findviewbyid, android-identifiers

In an XML file, we can assign an ID to a view like `android:id="@+id/something"` and then call `findViewById()`, but when creating a view programmatically, how do I assign an ID?

I think `setId()` is not the same as default assignment. `setId()` is extra.

Can anybody correct me?

Comment: Subset: how to generate unique IDs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts

Answer (score 538, accepted):

### Android `id` overview

An Android `id` is an integer commonly used to identify views; this `id` can be assigned via XML (when possible) and via code (programmatically.) The `id` is most useful for getting references for XML-defined `View`s generated by an `Inflater` (such as by using `setContentView`.)

#### Assign `id` via `XML`

- Add an attribute of `android:id="@+id/`somename`"` to your view.
- When your application is built, the `android:id` will be assigned a **unique** `int` for use in code.
- Reference your `android:id`'s `int` value in code using "`R.id.`somename" (effectively a constant.)
- *this `int` can change from build to build* so **never copy an id** from `gen/`package.name/`R.java`, just use "`R.id.`somename".
- (Also, an `id` assigned to a `Preference` in XML is not used when the `Preference` generates its `View`.)

#### Assign `id` via code (programmatically)

- Manually set `id`s using `someView.setId(`int`);`
- The `int` must be positive, but is otherwise arbitrary- it can be whatever you want (keep reading if this is frightful.)
- *For example, if creating and numbering several views representing items, you could use their item number.*

#### Uniqueness of `id`s

- `XML`-assigned `id`s will be unique.
- Code-assigned `id`s do *not* have to be unique
- Code-assigned `id`s can (theoretically) conflict with `XML`-assigned `id`s.
- These conflicting `id`s won't matter if queried correctly *(keep reading)*.

#### When (and why) conflicting `id`s don't matter

- `findViewById(int)` will iterate depth-first recursively through the view hierarchy *from the View you specify* and return the first `View` it finds with a matching `id`.
- As long as there are no code-assigned `id`s assigned before an XML-defined `id` in the hierarchy, `findViewById(R.id.somename)` will always return the XML-defined View so `id`'d.

#### Dynamically Creating Views and Assigning `ID`s

- In layout XML, define an empty `ViewGroup` with `id`.
- *Such as a `LinearLayout` with `android:id="@+id/placeholder"`.*
- Use code to populate the placeholder `ViewGroup` with `View`s.
- If you need or want, assign any `id`s that are convenient to each view.
- Query these child views using placeholder.findViewById(convenientInt);
- API 17 introduced `View.generateViewId()` which allows you to generate a unique ID.

**If you choose to keep references to your views around**, be sure to instantiate them with `getApplicationContext()` and be sure to set each reference to null in `onDestroy`. Apparently *leaking* the `Activity` (hanging onto it after is is destroyed) is wasteful.. :)

#### Reserve an XML `android:id` for use in code

*API 17 introduced* `View.generateViewId()` *which generates a unique ID.* (Thanks to take-chances-make-changes for pointing this out.)*

If your `ViewGroup` cannot be defined via XML (or you don't want it to be) you can reserve the id via XML to ensure it remains unique:

**Here, *values/ids.xml* defines a custom `id`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="reservedNamedId" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

**Then once the ViewGroup or View has been created, you can attach the custom id**

```
myViewGroup.setId(R.id.reservedNamedId);
```

### Conflicting `id` example

For clarity by way of obfuscating example, lets examine what happens when there is an `id` conflict behind the scenes.

**layout/mylayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

*To simulate a conflict, lets say our latest build assigned `R.id.placeholder`(`@+id/placeholder`) an `int` value of* `12`..

Next, **MyActivity.java** defines some adds views programmatically (via code):

```
int placeholderId = R.id.placeholder; // placeholderId==12
// returns *placeholder* which has id==12:
ViewGroup placeholder = (ViewGroup)this.findViewById(placeholderId);
for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
    TextView tv = new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());
    // One new TextView will also be assigned an id==12:
    tv.setId(i);
    placeholder.addView(tv);
}
```

So `placeholder` and one of our new `TextView`s both have an `id` of 12! But this isn't really a problem if we query placeholder's child views:

```
// Will return a generated TextView:
 placeholder.findViewById(12);

// Whereas this will return the ViewGroup *placeholder*;
// as long as its R.id remains 12: 
Activity.this.findViewById(12);
```

*Not so bad

Comment: In addition to this, it might be useful for someone in coding similiar solutions to be aware of View.generateViewId() in API > 17 for non-conflicting IDs

Comment: Note that `findViewById` does a depth-first exploration, so "As long as there are no code-assigned ids assigned above an XML-defined id in the hierarchy" isn't technically correct; it's "before" rather than "above".

Comment: In more recent versions of the Android developer tools, programmatically setting the ID to an arbitrary value will be flagged as a compiler error. The value is expected to be an actual resource ID.

Comment: I believe this was even the case when I answered this five years ago - that's why the custom id's had to be defined in `ids.xml` . For truly arbitrary ID's, use `View.generateViewId()` (API 17). (Please clarify your point if I've missed it.)

Comment: > (Also, an id assigned to a Preference in XML is not used when the Preference generates its View.)
Very interested about that. My code inherits from `PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat` it seems like ids from `R.id` do not match the ones view hierarchy. This way I cannot find the view by ID.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use the `View.setId(integer)` for this. In the XML, even though you're setting a String id, this gets converted into an integer. Due to this, you can use any (positive) Integer for the `Views`  you add programmatically.

> According to `View` documentation
>
> > The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy.
> >     The identifier should be a positive number.
>
> So you can use any positive integer you like, but in this case there
>   can be some views with equivalent id's. If you want to search for some
>   view in hierarchy calling to setTag with some key objects may be
>   handy.

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714510/993266).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can call `setId(value)` in any view with any (positive) integer value that you like and then find it in the parent container using `findViewById(value)`. Note that it is valid to call `setId()` with the same value for different sibling views, but `findViewById()` will return only the first one.

Comment: Note that you have to use an integer greater than zero.

Comment: though **findViewById(int) will iterate recursively through the view hierarchy from the View you specify and return the first View it finds with a matching id** specified in 1st answer is most accurate.

Comment: Yeah, calling `findViewById` on a known ancestor is a good idea for performance reasons, but it doesn't guarantee it will find an immediate child if there is one with the correct ID.