# ViewGroup.onRestoreInstanceState() not called when inflated programatically

Tags: android, android-view

I've got a `ViewGroup` which will fire `onRestoreInstanceState()` if inflated by my activity 
`setContentView()`. If I try to inflate it with `getLayoutInflater().inflate()`, then it won't.

I've tried to set an ID for it as said in [Restoring view hierarchy from saved state does not restore views added programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714265/restoring-view-hierarchy-from-saved-state-does-not-restore-views-added-programat). I also have an ID in the layout file, and `getID()` returns the same every activity recreation, yet it won't restore nor save the instance state.

How can I overcome this?

(Edit) Code I'm using at the moment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); //this code will work as intended
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    View content = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    setContentView(content); //this code will also work
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.another_layout);
    View content = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null); //now this view won't fire the method
}
```

The point is that I don't want to use that view as my layout for the activity. I need to inflate it some other way.

Comment: Post the code you tried

Comment: I don't think it's quite clear what you're trying to achieve with the third incarnation of `onCreate()`

Comment: I want to inflate it to add the view to another using `addView`. The code abouve is just what I know that makes any difference.