# OnSaveInstaceState and dynamically generated layouts and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

On this [documentation page about onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) I read:

> The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance
>   state for you by calling onSaveInstanceState() on each view in the
>   hierarchy that has an id, ...

and interpret as:

- if I generate a `LinearLayout L` containing an `ImageView I` and a `Fragment F`
- and I assign an ID to `L`, `I`, and `L`
- then `L`, `I`, and `F` are saved when `onSaveInstanceState(.)` is called

However, this does not happen: all the dynamically generated views are not restored if I terminate and re-open the app.

The code follows:

```
PacketEditorFragment packetFragment = PacketEditorFragment.newInstance();
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.packetFragmentContainer);

LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

int layoutId = IDS++;
String fragmentTag = FRAGMENT_TAG + layoutId;

linearLayout.setId(layoutId);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

vg.addView(linearLayout);

DeleteImageView deleteFragmentIV = new DeleteImageView(this, layoutId, fragmentTag);
deleteFragmentIV.setId(layoutId);
deleteFragmentIV.setOnClickListener(this);
deleteFragmentIV.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_delete);
linearLayout.addView(deleteFragmentIV);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(linearLayout.getId(), packetFragment, fragmentTag)
                .commit();
```

Is that piece of documentation valid also for `View`s that are generated dinamically?

There is another point which is a little obscure to me: What about the `Fragment`, that has not an ID (it is added using a `String tag`). Should I save and restore its state programmatically? The `DeleteImageView` stores a reference to a `Fragment` instance and deletes it in the `OnClick` listener method.

I have seen that there is way to restore a given instance of a fragment, but is it possible to have this behaviour for free? Even if they are generated dynamically, they are still part of the view hierarchy of the activity.

Comment: did you try to assign R.id. something?

Comment: Do you mean to the fragment?

Comment: no,  i mean your Views,  layout and image view

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what elements you are referring to. Besides those generated dynamically, whose ids are set programmatically (except for the `Fragment`), everything else has an id.

Comment: your layout is created by you,  right?  set its id to R.id.simething

Comment: Any dynamically created views by configuration change will be vanished and this is irrespective of whether it had id or not. You should create them again in your `onCreate` or somewhere else.

Comment: Is there any documentation I can read about this? The doc I cited does not speak about static/dynamic views, only about id.

Comment: @AntonioSesto Do you exactly know what happens when a device rotates?

Comment: I think I did, but your answer forced me to think 'may be not' (then an explanation concerning the doc I cited would be kind). Please notice I am not speaking about instance fields getting destroyed and causing bad accesses, but to components living in the view hierarchy.

Comment: the code you posted: is it executed in onCreate?

Comment: @pskink No. The fragments contain optional data that the user is free to add or not. The static GUI contains a plus button: its onClickListener executes the code above.

Comment: no wonder that you dont see your dynamically created linearLayout and deleteFragmentIV: how android could add them?

Comment: There's another container (FrameLayout) in the same XML layout containing one of two different fragments: the user decides. This container has no problems in remembering which fragment it was hosting at the time the app was killed: I did not add any specific code. This makes perfect sense according to the documentation. The problem is connected to elements that are not specified in the XML file: the doc only speaks about ID, it should work.

Comment: when the device rotates you create the "normal static" views by calling setContentView but you don't add "dynamic" views: "linearLayout" and "deleteFragmentIV", that's why you don't see them

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem after reading the accepted answer of this question [Restoring view hierarchy from saved state does not restore views added programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714265/restoring-view-hierarchy-from-saved-state-does-not-restore-views-added-programat).

Basically, when the activity is restored, you need to add the views you added programmatically **with the same ID they had the first time you created them**.

This approach does not make any sense to me: starting from the static layout provided in the XML file the system has all the info needed to first re-create the layout the activity had when it was killed and then pass the saved `Bundle` to each component. However, this is the way it works: you need to re-create the layout and assign to each component the same ID it had.