# findFragmentById always returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm defining an ID for my fragment in the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/test_fragment"
...
```

Then I add this fragment in the activity's onCreate method:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This is all working fine. Replacing fragments and is also working.

Later I'm trying to retrieve this fragment by its ID in one of the activity's methods:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.test_fragment);
```

Doing so leads to myFragment being `null`. Always.

When I try to do the same with tags instead of IDs I can retrieve the fragment by its tag without any problems:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, "testfragment");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

...

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("testfragment");
```

Why can't findFragmentById find the fragment, but findFragmentByTag does so? Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `(MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`R.id.test_fragment` is not the ID of your fragment but the id of your LinearLayout

Calling `add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)` will add a fragment without a tag.
So or you use `add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)` and you get back your fragment using your tag (as an ID)

Comment: This is a valid workaround but did not answer the question. Have the look at the docs for a proper description. The docs say the id is either assigned when inflating the fragment from xml or is the container id when added using a transaction... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)

Comment: See this answer for a good description on programatically assigning id's: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13241629/857681

Comment: If a Fragment is added without an id, can't you find it using the id of the container it's placed in? I'm pretty sure that's a thing.

Comment: Mike T is right. The docs explicitly say you are supposed to be able to use the ID of the container of the fragment in `getFragmentById()`.

Comment: You don't have to use `add(...)` with tag. And the docs are right. You just have to use the correct `FragmentManager` instance to make `getFragmentById()` work in the way you expect it to work. Check my answer below for additional information.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `<FrameLayout>` tag as a container in your layout file.  Later to replace the fragments from your activity dynamically, you can use the ID of the `<FrameLayout>` container to replace the fragments in your activity.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/test_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/test_fragment"
```

it should be a `fragment` not a `LinearLayout`

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.yourfragment"
            android:id="@+id/test_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: So what do I have to change? I can't define my layout with <fragment> as top node. I can't add the fragments in the xml layout of the activity since I have to remove them later on.

Comment: Ok than you can not define fragment in the layout. If you need to retrive the linerarlayout you have to use the inflater parameter in the onCreateView

Answer (score 4):

I was using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in my layout while calling `getFragmentManager()` which actually searched for `android.app.Fragment` subclasses and I got `null`. 
So the fix was to call `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead.

In general make sure the package of a fragment you are subclassing and using in your layout is the same returned by the corresponding `FragmentManager` which performs search.

Answer (score 3):

Or, you should have instead used :

```
(MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

Answer (score 2):

`R.id.test_fragment` is your `LinearLayout` ID not your Fragment.

You can define and id on a fragment when it is inflated from an xml like in this sample http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Adding

Answer (score 2):

The reasons mentioned above are valid but another possible reason is that you are trying to search for the fragment while being in a fragment this also results in `fragmentManager.findFragmentById` to return null. We should use `childFragmentManager.findFragmentById` to find the fragment inside a fragment.
According to the official documentation.

`public final androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager getChildFragmentManager()`

> Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments
>   inside of this Fragment.

Comment: I know it's against stackoverflow rules, but just upvoting is not enough, you are legend.

Answer (score 1):

```
FragmentB fragmentB = 
(FragmentB) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerb);

if(fragmentB != null)
{
   fragmentB.showuserResponse(msg);
}
```

Use container id as fragment id. And then check for null reference.

Answer (score 0):

> fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);
>
> MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.test_fragment);

Please notice the difference.

You should pass R.id.fragment_container as the argument to `findFragmentById`, as you pass it to the add function, instead of `R.id.test_fragment`

By the way , according to the inner implementation of the two functions, it should be right that the id can be
that of its container view.