# After findFragmentById, how do I call a method in my fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The google documentation says that I can "*call methods in the fragment by acquiring a reference to the Fragment from FragmentManager, using findFragmentById()*"

This part makes sense:

```
SelectionFragment fragment = (SelectionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);
```

What I don't understand is how I am actually now supposed to call the methods. I've tried everything I can think of. I tried this, and I get a Null Pointer Exception on this line:

```
String fbID = fragment.userIdView.getText().toString();
```

I know there are a TON of questions on stack overflow about findFragmentById returning null, but I haven't found a solution in any of them. I have no idea how to identify where the problem is.

To be clear, selectionFragment is the ID of my fragment set in the xml:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.androidhive.SelectionFragment"
      android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: which part of chain of method calls is null? ie fragment, or fragment.userIdView, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure, is there a way to find that out based on the logcat?

Comment: you can always do if (fragment == null) System.out.println("frag is null");

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it is saying that fragment is null. In that case, should I try one of the solutions involving giving the fragment a tag instead?

Comment: yes,  I think I ran into this recently also and that worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833666/findfragmentbyid-always-returns-null

Comment: Take a look at this question/answer, I found it very helpful when I had this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833666/findfragmentbyid-always-returns-null