# Calling a Fragment Method in an Activity causes a Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, fragment, butterknife

I want to call the Fragment Method when I click on the FloatingActionButton.
I am using Butterknife.

Error:

> PID: 9956                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.fischerdaniel.testapp.FirstFragment.setTvText()' on a null object reference

The part of the MainActicity:

```
  @OnClick({R.id.fab_one, R.id.fab_two, R.id.fab_three}) public void test(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.fab_three:
                FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_first);
                firstFragment.setTvText();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

The part of the Fragment:

```
    @BindView(R.id.et_one) EditText etOne;
    @BindView(R.id.et_two) EditText etTwo;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_one) TextView tvOne;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_two) TextView tvTwo;

    private Unbinder unbinder;

   @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }

    protected void setTvText() {
        tvOne.setText(etOne.getText());
        tvTwo.setText(etTwo.getText());
    }
```

Comment: you are calling it by refrence

Answer (score 1):

See this link: [findFragmentById always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833666/findfragmentbyid-always-returns-null)

When you create your fragment, use:

```
add(int id, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

and then to get your fragment, use:

```
findFragmentByTag(String tag)
```

Comment: the fragment is in a viewpager

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onMenuItemClick(View clickedView, int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 1:
             fragmentChanger("Notifications",new notifyFragment());
           break;
        case 2:
             fragmentChanger("QR Code",new qrFragment());
            break;
        case 3:
            fragmentChanger("User ID",new MainFragment());
            break;
        case 4:
            fragmentChanger("Settings",new settingsFragment());
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

//function that does the trasaction when a fragment object is passed
//R.id.container is my default frame
public void fragmentChanger(String title, Object expectedFragment){
   // mToolBarTextView.setText(title);
    transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, (Fragment) expectedFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Looks detailed but could use some explanatory text. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the fragment is in a viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Call your fragment method from Activity in like below,

it worked for me

```
FirstFragment firstFragment =(FirstFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0); 

firstFragment.yourmethod();
```

Here 0 is your fragment position.