# NullPointerException while retrieving fragments by ID

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to call a function of a given fragment from the outside: both from the main activity and from another fragment of the same level. In both cases the fragment retrieved with findFragmentById is null. I also tried with findFragmentByTag but with the same result.

CALL FOR TARGET FRAGMENT FUNCTION

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();//if added by xml
MainFragmentLDash2 myFragment = (MainFragmentLDash2) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fd2);
if(myFragment == null){
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    myFragment.mediaDraw();
}
```

FUNCTION IN THE TARGET FRAGMENT I WANT TO CALL

```
public void mediaDraw() {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "drawFRAGMENT2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

FRAME'S XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fd2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:tag="firstFragmentWrapperDash2">

</FrameLayout>
```

LOGCAT

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:109)
  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:268)
  at design.ubris.myuni.MainFragmentLDash2.mediaDraw(MainFragmentLDash2.java:101)
  at design.ubris.myuni.MainFragmentLSegr1.OnAsyncTaskComplete(MainFragmentLSegr1.java:171)
  at design.ubris.myuni.URLDataReader.onPostExecute(URLDataReader.java:112)
  at design.ubris.myuni.URLDataReader.onPostExecute(URLDataReader.java:26)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:692)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:709)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [findFragmentById always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833666/findfragmentbyid-always-returns-null)

Comment: yes. The find method get activated by a background method that read a webpage and take many seconds to call it. It should be already instanciated.

Comment: You should be using getSupportFragmentManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you have not yet added the fragment to the fragment stack.

Ensure you do this:

```
MainFragmentLDash2 myFragment = new MainFragmentLDash2();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fd2, myFragment).commit();
```

now you can call the fragment method

`myFragment.mediaDraw();`

Comment: now it not recognize the function in the target fragment. "Cannot resolve method mediaDraw()"

Comment: Try this  MainFragmentLDash2 myFragment = new MainFragmentLDash2();

Comment: its the same you wrote before

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use `findFragmentByTag`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag( "PREFS_FRAGMENT" );
```

Just make sure you pass the tag when you create the fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new YourFragment(), "PREFS_FRAGMENT")
                    .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log you attached, it seems you are receiving that `NullPointerExeception` for the context you passed in **Toast** creation.

`Toast.makeText(getContext().....`

You need to replace this *getContext()* by *getActivity()* like this:

`Toast.makeText(getActivity()....`

Comment: I tried with getActivity (),
getActivity (). getApplicationContext (), getContext (). getApplicationContext (), but it does not work.

Comment: same crash as before?

Comment: it enter in a loop: it come back to the previous activity, then enter in the in the target one, and so on.

Comment: yes an infinite loop. Now it recognize the fragment that is not more null, but it has this beaviour when i call target fragment function.

Comment: the code snippets you attached that show only the reason behind crash and my answer was to fix that `NullPointerException` crash, which is correct. Now you are experiencing a new issue, which might be caused by another part of your code flow. I would suggest to post a separate question with other relevant codes to describe the new problem, since you already got the answer of your original problem. And please consider of marking my answer as accepted.

Comment: hi @Giorgio, if you kindly consider marking this answer accepted which resolved your crash in the question, other peoples facing similar trouble may get help from it.