# How to get the id of a dynamically created textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-view, findviewbyid

I'm trying to dynamically add and remove TextView for an android app I'm making but I'm running into difficulty setting and getting the TextView's id. I seem to be getting null pointer exception's for the last two lines of code (et.setText and ll.removeView). Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can dynamically set and get the id of a textview? Apparently .setId doesn't seem to work, or more likely, I'm doing it wrong.

```
//surrounding non-relevant code removed
EditText et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_tags);
et.setText("");

TextView nTv = new TextView(view.getContext()); 
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lparams.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
nTv.setLayoutParams(lparams);   
nTv.setId(tag_id);
nTv.setText(str.substring(0, str.length()-1));
nTv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);               
nTv.setTextSize(20);
final LinearLayout linl = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
linl.addView(nTv);

nTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_tags);
        TextView t = ((TextView)v);
        et.setText(t.getText().toString());
        linl.removeView(v);

    }
});
```

Comment: You can assign as what said in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically you can get it.

Comment: You can see this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextView` doesn't contain all the children in the layout, the `LinearLayout` does. Make `linl` `final`, then you can use it in `nTV`'s `OnClickListener` (As long as the `view` contains the layout. If not, you're going to need to make some decisions about what exactly you want to achieve - making a reference to the layout earlier on might work).

```
final LinearLayout linl = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
linl.addView(nTv);

nTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText et = (EditText) linl.findViewById(R.id.edittext_tags);
        TextView t = ((TextView)v);
        et.setText(t.getText().toString());
        linl.removeView(v);
    }
```

With your approach the id is not really needed, since you always have a reference to the View.

However, if you wanted to work with views (very redundant example, but it's for the sake of explanation):

```
nTv.setId(tag_id);
linl.addView(nTv);

TextView duplicateTextViewReference (TextView) linl.findViewById (tag_id);
```

Comment: Got it, thanks for taking the time to explain in detail, very helpful.

Comment: I also added a bit about ids, but the idea's the same - Parent View contains children, so always work with the parent when wanting to access children.