# What should I use to find my dynamically created TextViews

Tags: android, tablerow

I has to ask you how to find my Views, I created them dynamically because all information about Texts were in my string-array, and now I would like to find it to store this in Class by getters, to use it in another classes, in feature I would like to make backend to store information thats why I chose class for temporary solution.

Thats my code

```
sportlist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.btnsport);
    for(j=0;j<sportlist.length;j++){
        sporthash.put(j,sportlist[j]);
        System.out.println(sporthash);
    }


//Here I create my TableRow with TextView

    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lp.height = 120;
    lp.setMargins(8,8,8,8);

    for(j=0;j<sportlist.length;j++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);
        final TextView t = new TextView(getActivity());
        t.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        t.setText(sporthash.get(j));
        t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        t.setClickable(true);
        t.setTextSize(18);
        t.setId(j);
        t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sport_false);
        t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Then after this I have saving button, which send information to my Storage.class. I try to set `t.setId(j)` and find it by new `TextView` h, `h.findViewById(j)` but its return strage code. I would to find Views with `t.BackgroundResource(R.drawable.sport_true)` and send them to my Storage.class.

Thats my button, in for I tryed to find my views, so what solution would be best ?

```
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Storage sto = new Storage();
            sto.setAge(BirthDate.getText().toString());
            sto.setImage(civ);
            sto.setLocation(Map.getText().toString());
            System.out.println(Map.getText().toString());
            for(j=0;j<sportlist.length;j++) {



            }

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),ProfilActivity.class);
            startActivity(newIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Store them in an array ... but obviously class called "Storage" shouldn't know about UI at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the id of a dynamically created textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575169/how-to-get-the-id-of-a-dynamically-created-textview)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `setId` here, because `setId` should be used with `generateViewId`:

From documentation of [`generateViewId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()):

> **generateViewId**
>
> Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int). This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.

When you're trying to set the id with `setId()` there's probability your id is colliding with auto-generated id by the Android Studio. So, you need to ensure the id is unique.

You can use [`setTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) and [`getTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) to avoid the problem with `setId()`