# Android create ID programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am looking for creating ID in code without using XML declaration. For example, I have code, where I programmatically create View like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);

  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
  View v = new View(this);
  v.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
  ll.addView(v, 100, 100);

}
```

and I can add `v.setId(50)`, but I would like add `v.setId(R.id.some_id)` and I wouldn't like add `some_id` into xml file, this option I know.

My question is, how to create `R.id.some_id` programmatically without setting it in XML file. Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Refer to this fantastic answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13241629/586859

R.* references are used explicitly to access ***resources***.  What you are trying to do is not really possible, but maybe you could us something like the following section from the above answer:

#### Reserve an XML `android:id` for use in code

If your `ViewGroup` cannot be defined via XML (or you don't want it to be) you can reserve the id via XML to ensure it remains unique:

**Here, *values/ids.xml* defines a custom `id`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="reservedNamedId" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

**Then once the ViewGroup or View has been created, you can attach the custom id**

```
myViewGroup.setId(R.id.reservedNamedId);
```

Comment: I think the question asker explicitly does NOT want to use the XML: "how create R.id.some_id programmatically without set it in XML file"

Comment: @RvdK Exactly.  I understand that much but I was banking on the OG poster to read through the link I posted to understand that R.* is explicitly for resources. The section I posted was only a referral to a solution as close as it really gets to what is desired.

Comment: Mz point is, if is possible create id with v.setId(int id) than maybe is possible create R.* without XML declaration, maybe not, i search this topic several times with no accetable results.

Comment: @user1173536 No, it is not possible. Think of your resources as hard coded.  You cannot dynamically create them and they must be unique.  You can only reference and use them.