# How to convert java id in form of number in a character ASCII string?

Tags: java, android, xml, string

I code some TextViews programatically and I want to provide them with ids. In the xml file I would have done something like:

```
android:id="@+id/btn0"
```

but in the .java file I'm allowed to set the id only as a number:

```
t1.setId(3);
```

Is there any possibility to convert "btn0" in a number and then to use findbyid() functions using as a parameter the string "btn0"?

P.S. I experimented logging the value of R.id.btn0 and I get a number : 2131361887

```
Log.d("aaa", Integer.toString(R.id.btn0));
```

Is there any possibility to convert this number back in string of ASCII characters?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android create ID programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139310/android-create-id-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you really need is ids predeclared in resources but not assigned to any view in a layout. If you want to do that, you may create id resource, i.e. `ids.xml` inside `values` resource directory. The ids in that file should be declared like this:

```
<resources>
    <item name="btn0" type="id"/>
    <item name="open_url" type="id"/>
    ...
</resources>
```

After that, you will be able to use those ids as normal, from the generated R class (`R.id.btn0`).
The only thing I don't understand is why you need to search for a programmatically created view if you already have a reference to it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Well, I don't have yet the refference yet, I want to create lots of textviews in a for loop and assign them the id btn and then the value of i like btn0.