# How to add a fragment to a programmatically generated layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I have the following code working which generates fragments, but only if I am adding them to a linear layout which exists in my XML file.

```
LinearLayout fragmentsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments);
FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();

Fragment myFrag= new ImageFragment();
fragTransaction.add(R.id.foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments, myFrag , "fragment" + fragCount);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Now what if I want to add that fragment to a linear layout that does not already exist in the XML file such as

```
LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout();
```

Part 2:

```
    Fragment frag1 = generateAppropriateFragment(type1);
    Fragment frag2 = generateAppropriateFragment(type2);

    LinearLayout fragmentsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.foodItemActvity_linearLayout_fragments);
    LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    rowLayout.setId(12345); // add counter to end

    fragmentsLayout.addView(rowLayout);     
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rowLayout.getId(), frag1, "fragment_grandchild" + fragCount).commit();
    fragCount++;
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rowLayout.getId(), frag2, "fragment_grandchild" + fragCount).commit();
    fragCount++;
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

At some point, I suppose you will add your programatically created LinearLayout to some root layout that you defined in .xml.
This is just a suggestion of mine and probably one of many solutions, but it works:
Simply **set an ID for the programatically created layout**, and add it to the root layout that you defined in .xml, and then **use the set ID to add the Fragment.**

It could look like this:

```
LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout();
rowLayout.setId(whateveryouwantasid);
// add rowLayout to the root layout somewhere here

FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();   

Fragment myFrag = new ImageFragment();
fragTransaction.add(rowLayout.getId(), myFrag , "fragment" + fragCount);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Simply **choose whatever Integer value you want** for the ID:

```
rowLayout.setId(12345);
```

If you are using the above line of code not just once, it would probably be smart to **figure out a way to create unique-IDs**, in order to **avoid duplicates**.

**UPDATE:**

*Here is the full code of how it should be done:*
(this code is tested and works)
I am adding two Fragments to a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, resulting in the Fragments being aligned next to each other. Please also be aware, that **I used a fixed height and width** of 200dp, so that **one Fragment does not use the full screen** as it would with "match_parent".

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        LinearLayout fragContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llFragmentContainer);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        ll.setId(12345);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ll.getId(), TestFragment.newInstance("I am frag 1"), "someTag1").commit();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ll.getId(), TestFragment.newInstance("I am frag 2"), "someTag2").commit();

        fragContainer.addView(ll);
    }
}
```

**TestFragment.java:**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TestFragment newInstance(String text) {

        TestFragment f = new TestFragment();

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("text", text);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragText)).setText(getArguments().getString("text"));     
        return v;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment.xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFragText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the result of the above code: (the two Fragments are aligned next to each other)
[image: result]

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do!!  Only thing is what must I set the id as? Cause it wants an INT and normally in the xml files the id is a string ?

Comment: This will absolutely work. @Zapnologica Look on SO to find how to generate unique ids. But, it shouldn't be a problem to use something like `647589`.

Comment: Just choose whatever Integer you want as the id :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically >> Good Link

Comment: @Phil I solved the compiling issues, but now it wont display my row layout. Please see my original question i added a part 2 which is my code. it runs but i dont see the two fragments.

Comment: Are you setting the id for your rowlayout? try this line: fragmentsLayout.addView(rowLayout); before the fragmenttransaction

Comment: @Phil Yes i am setting its id. And I tried with it before still same thing. It compiles and runs. the fragments on create methods run. but no display. my code displays if I just add the fragment to the FragmentLayout. But not with the row layout.

Comment: Allright, give me a second I will create a project and try it out and then post the solution here.

Comment: Updated the answer and posted the working code. I tested it on emulator and on my device.

Comment: @Phil PLease see mt edit to the original post, i updated my code.  When i add both fragments then my display is blank, but i can see the space of where the 2 fragments are meant to load. it even gets bigger as the image in the fragment loads. But if I remove the one it works fine.

Comment: Well maybe there is something wrong with the code inside your fragment, where you inflate. What does generateAppropriateFragment() do? See my updated answer please, I changed the code and now I add two Fragments to the LinearLayout, it still works fine.

Comment: @Phil you dont think it has something to do with not using supportv4? cause i am using plain `import android.app.Fragment;`

Comment: Just changed it all to support library and it still does the same. its so weird.

Comment: I dont think so since im also using android.app.Fragment. Please post the code of one of your Fragments and the code of generateAppropriateFragment()

Comment: I think my issue is with my layout params, i just changed the linear layout to vertical and it displayed. SO its not persay a fragment issue I must just play around with the settings. @Phil Thanks SO much for your help. Really appreciate it

Comment: Please take a close look at my code and the explanation of it. If you set your Fragments width and height to match_parent, one Fragment will not be displayed. You are welcome ;)

Comment: I have still be battling, I can add 2 buttons and a fragment and a variation of those combos to the layout, but i cant add 2 fragments, it just will not work.

Comment: @Phil Ok i think i have come right. i See you set your fragments widths manually. How can I do it so that each fragment is 50% of the screens width wide?

Comment: But root layout is not generated programmatically

Comment: I'd recommend using `View.generateViewId()` to generate a view ID.

Comment: Once screen is rotated. I got duplicate of fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working code to add a fragment e.g 3 times to a vertical LinearLayout (xNumberLinear).
You can change number 3 with any other number or take a number from a spinner!

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            LinearLayout linearDummy = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            linearDummy.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This function works on newer versions of android", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                linearDummy.setId(View.generateViewId());
            }
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(linearDummy.getId(), new SomeFragment(),"someTag1").commit();

            xNumberLinear.addView(linearDummy);
        }
```