# My fragment does not appear in the main activity

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

i added the fragment using XML and it worked fine , but when i tried to add it dynamically it did not appear in the main activity

FragmentActivity.java:

```
package com.example.pc.learn_again;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;

public class FragmentActivity2 extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainfragment2);

    //adding the fragment using Java code---dynamically ya3ni//
    //create an object of the intended frag//
    Fragment3 frag = new Fragment3();
    //get the manager
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    //start the transaction
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    //add to the layout
    transaction.add(R.id.mylayout,frag,"fragment3");//--note: the parameters used are 1- the id of the main layout 2- the intended fragment 3- a key for future use//
    //finish using the below
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

Fragment3.java:

```
package com.example.pc.learn_again;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3,container,false);
}
}
```

the fragment3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/highlighted_text_material_light">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the mainfragment2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mylayout">

</LinearLayout>
```

i checked all of the above and the connection between the xml files and the classes and all are correct though when i test it the fragment does not show in the activity

Comment: checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296868/how-to-add-a-fragment-to-a-programmatically-generated-layout

Comment: Some things that I'm seeing, without testing your code:
- try to import android.support.v4.* classes for your FragmentManager, FragmentTransaction and Fragment
- try to change your activity to extend FragmentActivity
- use different onCreate() method - the one without PersistentState

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mainfragment2.xml:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that you're using the wrong onCreate(), so your activity code never runs.

[onCreate(Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) is the standard method which is always called when an activity is created. [onCreate(Bundle, PersistableBundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle%29) is only called if you have the [persistableMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#persistableMode) tag set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `FrameLayout` inside `LinearLayout` in `mainfragment2.xml` first:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mylayout">

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, place `Fragment3` into this `FrameLayout` using `replace()` method:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment3).commit();
```

Since `Fragment` was added in API level 11, you can use `getSupportFragmentManager()` which provided by Support Library to the make pre-Honeycomb devices support `Fragment` too.