# Here Map Android w/o Using Layout With Error: ERROR: Cannot initialize with a null Context

Tags: android, here-api

We are using here map android SDK. We don't use layout at all. So we are stock here about how to use it.

First of all, **we need to put the map inside a View(or RelativeLayout)**.

Secondly, when we try to start the map with the following code:

```
MapFragment map_fragment = null;
//...
map_fragment = new MapFragment();

// how do we add the map_fragment as a "sub-view" of another View/RelativeLayout

map_fragment(new OnEngineInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void  onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
       if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
           map_fragment.getMapGesture().
                addOnGestureListener(gestureListener);
               // throws errors at this line
       } else {
       }

    //...
    }
}
```

It throws an error:

```
ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment,UNKNOWN,Unknown error occurred.,java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot initialize with a null Context
I:     at com.nokia.maps.ee.a(Preconditions.java:19)
I:     at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.b(MapsEngine.java:355)
I:     at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine.a(MapsEngine.java:343)
I:     at com.here.android.mpa.common.MapEngine.init(MapEngine.java:129)
I:     at com.nokia.maps.br.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:126)
I:     at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment.init(MapFragment.java:108)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calling the init code before the application Context is created? The map fragment is a fragment and needs to be added into the fragment manager before it can be used.

An example stack overflow answer to dynamically adding a fragment would be the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296868/how-to-add-a-fragment-to-a-programmatically-generated-layout).