# Set id for spinner programmatically

Tags: android, android-spinner, resource-id

It feels like I am missing something but how do you set the resource ID when making a spinner programmatically?  (for example R.id.myspinner)

Thanx JP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically

Comment: thanks, sorry for the stupid question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySpinner.setId(int) if MySpinner is the reference to the spinner.