# (Android) How to set the id of an xml component through Java?

Tags: android, android-layout

These is how I set id in XML android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
assuming i don't have that in XML,
what I want is to set multiple id in Java, these is my expected output if I want to call them:

```
findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)
findViewById(R.id.checkBox2)
findViewById(R.id.checkBox3)
findViewById(R.id.checkBox4)
```

I know my question is vague but anyone have an idea??
This is my code..

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_information);

    Resources res = getResources(); 
    String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);   

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lMainIng);
    for(int x=0; x<planets.length; x++){
        CheckBox testView = new CheckBox(this);
        testView.setText(planets[x]);
        testView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  //--->        testView.setId(x);
  //just a test what would be the id result
  //--->        testView.setText(R.id.lMainIng);
        layout.addView(testView);
    }

  }
```

I think my question is somewhat wrong,..
What i really want to ask is how to identify the id that I've just generate for the specific components, in this particular activity..
i want to save those id's in an array but i don't know how to identify them..

Comment: can you go through this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically

Comment: you can use `setId(x);`

Comment: i've already checked that, however im totally new to android(sorry) and i dont get the nonconflicting id example he gave.. ive been trying to implicate that example for several hours.. :(

Comment: Code-assigned ids do not have to be unique

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

Enter getTag/setTag:

```
testView.setTag(1);
testView.setTag(2);
```

to retrive u can use :

```
myValue = textView.getTag();
```

OR use

```
findViewByTag method
```