# Getting R.id for generated checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox

I am dynamically generating checkboxes in my program like so:

```
public void addNewItem(String item, TableLayout tablel) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(params);
    CheckBox item1 = new CheckBox(this);
    item1.setText(item);
    row.addView(item1);
    tablel.addView(row, i);
    i++;
```

From what I've been able to test, this work fine for adding checkboxes to my table. The problem I'm encountering is that I want to be able to have something happen when a checkbox is checked, which I am unsure of how to do without knowning the id. Is there some way to get around this or get the id of the checkbox that has been checked when the `onCheckBoxClick()` method is called?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the ID because you already have the checkbox as on object.

Use this:

```
item1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(item1.isChecked()){
                System.out.println("Checked");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Un-Checked");
            }
        }
    });
```

An other possibility:

```
item1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: You may also get the id from inside the onclick listener by calling  the getId method on the view, in this case it would be `v.getId()`. See the checkbox guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html) as it also talks about aanother method for setting the onClick method.

Comment: And you can also generate an id by youself by calling `v.setId(View.generateViewId())`;

Comment: I think the problem with this is that I plan on generating several checkboxes, each in their own table row. Then, if they get checked, I remove them. Therefore, I'm not sure this is totally what I want to use.

Comment: I do not see what the problem is with that

Answer (score 0):

Assign id via code (programmatically)

1.Manually set ids using `someView.setId(int);`

2.The int must be positive, but is otherwise arbitrary.
Then you can access that id.

It think this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have created `TableRow` and `CheckBox` you should set id pragmatically like this

```
public void addNewItem(String item, TableLayout tablel) {
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
row.setId(i);//i is a positive int value
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
row.setLayoutParams(params);
CheckBox item1 = new CheckBox(this);
row.setId(j);//j is a positive int value
item1.setText(item);
row.addView(item1);
tablel.addView(row, i);
i++;
```

[***You can check this SO question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically)

```
int chkBoxId = 10;
int tableRowId = 100;
String texts[] = {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4", "Text5"};
CheckBox[] chkBoxes;
private TableLayout tableLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dynamic_chk_box);
    tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    chkBoxes = new CheckBox[texts.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(params);
        chkBoxes[i] = new CheckBox(this);
        chkBoxes[i].setId(chkBoxId++);
        row.setId(tableRowId);//tableRowId is a positive int value
        chkBoxes[i].setText(texts[i]);
        row.addView(chkBoxes[i]);
        tableLayout.addView(row, i);
        tableRowId++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        chkBoxes[j].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(isChecked) {
                int checkedId = chkBoxes[j].getId();
                Toast.makeText(DynamicCheckBoxActivity.this, 
                        String.valueOf(checkedId), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                int unCheckedId = chkBoxes[j].getId();
                System.out.println("Uncheck ===> " + String.valueOf(unCheckedId));
            }
          }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but if I then wanted to check which has been checked, is there any easy way to recall that id once I set it?