# Seemingly similar pieces of code for RelativeLayouts work differently

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Both pieces are to place two objects near each other with a fixed size for one of them

Piece one. Works as supposed: dynamically filled scrollView takes all the space possible above the keyboard

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
root.addView(keyboardView, params);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, keyboardView.getId());
root.addView(scrollView, params);
```

Piece two. Supposed to place a button on the right and an editText taking the rest of the place to the left of the button. Instead, the editText ignores the button and takes the whole screen width, so the button is under it

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
container.addView(deleteButton, params);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, deleteButton.getId());
container.addView(editText, params);
```

Piece two remade in XML. For some reason, working as needed

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/item_deleteButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_editText" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_editText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/item_deleteButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you creating those `Views` (for example `deleteButton`) dynamically, or through an xml?

Comment: Dynamically. XML code has no connection with the java piece two - it's just to illustrate what I wanted to do. I can't see the diffefence between java and XML implementations though

Comment: Ok, so are you sure your `View` has viable `id`?

Comment: Was sure until this moment. Isn't an `id` attached to every `View` object on its construction?

Comment: No. `Id` is attached to a `View` only if you want it to be. So through `xml` if you use `android:id="@+id/some_id` or if you create a `View` dynamically with a method call `setId(int id)`.

Comment: Okay. And how to choose an `id` properly so that there will be no collisions with the others assigned before?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically

Comment: In my code, I've been using something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15442898/1993204

Comment: What is the role of the AtomicInteger in this ID generator? What problems can be encoutered if it is replaced with a usual `int` and a method similar to `compareAndSet`?

Comment: You should ask the author of the post, not me.