# Android: How to create resource ids for edit text created dynamically. so that it should show different ids when tested in uiautomationviewer

Tags: android, android-layout

'[Please find this attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ydIm.png)  I have created an XML file with only one edit text. and in java class i'm dynamically inflating the XML file to create multiple edit text fields. now the problem is resource id are same for all the edit text fields. so is there any way to give different resource ids. please help me.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText[] sample;
        Boolean Valid;
        ArrayList<String> obj_array = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayout root_layout;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            root_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            obj_array.add("abc");
            obj_array.add("def");
            obj_array.add("ghi");
            obj_array.add("jkl");
            assignToValue();
        }

        private void assignToValue() {
            sample = new EditText[obj_array.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < obj_array.size(); i++) {
       // here i'm dynamically creating edit text .
                View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.edittext,null);
                sample[i] = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit);
                sample[i].setText(obj_array.get(i));
                root_layout.addView(sample[i]);
            }
        }
    }'
```

Comment: You can dynamically create `edittext` where you can put dynamic id by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this could help you:

1. create a file `res/values/ids.xml` with a content like this for example (with the ids, that will be set dynamically):

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <item type="id" name="id1" />
       <item type="id" name="id2" />
       <item type="id" name="id3" />
   </resources>`
2. Then you could add in your java code lines like these:

   `edit1.setId(R.id.layout1);
   edit2.setId(R.id.layout2);
   edit3.setId(R.id.layout3);  //where edit1, edit2 and edit3 are sample dynamically created EditTexts for example`

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I'm creating dynamically so i would not know how many edittext will be there. how can i write it in ids.xml.

Comment: take a look at this stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically maybe it will help you

Comment: But if i use this also. it is not showing resource ids in UiAutomationViewer.

Comment: Hi I'm not sure why this is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Create a 16 Digit integer as base ID, say `baseId = 1234567890123450`
Set this as id for `Edittext` by method setId in your class (`editTextVariable.setId(baseId)`)
When a new `edittext` is inflated add 1 to `baseId` and set it to the newly inflated `edittext`.
For each newly added `edittext` add 1 to the previous id and set it.
Keep a count of number of `edittext` added in a variable.

Comment: ok  thank you for your answer. when I am going to test the app with UiAutomationViewer it takes id's only from xml file not from java(static only not dynamic). Then how I can get id's of the edittexts?