# Equivalent of android:layout_above="@+id/foo"

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-layoutparams

In XML you can do:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/foo"
```

to make a element be above another element `foo`.

How do I do this programatically?

While `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` can add the rule `RelativeLayout.ABOVE` that does not allow me to specify which element I want my view to be above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that does not allow me to specify which element I want my view to be above.

Sure it does

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int, int))

> anchor    The id of another view to use as an anchor, or a boolean value (represented as TRUE for true or 0 for false). For verbs that don't refer to another sibling (for example, ALIGN_WITH_PARENT_BOTTOM) just use -1.

There are two `addRule()` methods in the docs. Just use the one which takes a second param and give the id of the `View` you want it anchored above.

In fact, the one which you mention, explicitly says

> This method should only be used for constraints that **don't refer to another sibling**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score -1):

You have to set an id for the view. You can do myview.setId(id) or declare an id in a ressource file ids.xml and then setId(R.id.declared_id).

link: [How can I assign an ID to a view programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically)

Comment: I don't think answers my question.