# Generate ID in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I've created checkboxes programmatically, and i need to set layout_above for each of them( so they will be above each other).
this code works in loop, so it will generate few checkboxes, but i need to set id. how can I properly generate it?

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, checkBox.getId());
        checkBox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        checkBox.setWidth(getScreenWidth());
        checkBox.setText(questions.get(questionId).answers.get(index));
    ll.addView(checkBox);
```

Comment: checkBox.setId(int); to set id on each checkbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I assign an ID to a view programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically)

Comment: Not sure. I generate it in while loop, and it generates like 4-7 checkboxes.

Comment: Why not use a LinearLayout?

Answer (score 1):

```
   int CHECK_BOX_ID = 1;
 CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, checkBox.getId());
    checkBox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    checkBox.setWidth(getScreenWidth());
    checkBox.setId(CHECK_BOX_ID);
    CHECK_BOX_ID++;
    checkBox.setText(questions.get(questionId).answers.get(index));
ll.addView(checkBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 checkBox.setId(checkBoxId);
```

generate a random number and increment it within the loop.
This should probably do it.