# How to get dynamic check box id?

Tags: android, select, checkbox, dynamic, command

I make dynamic check box using below code in my project how i can get the check box id and make an command for it for example:

```
if(checkbox1.ischecked()==true){
//do 
}
```

Thank you in advance.

```
public void fetchContacts() {
    final LinearLayout Vll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Vll);

    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                        cb.setText(outputName+":"+outputNumber);
                        Vll.addView(cb);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store all references to all `CheckBox` in a `ArrayList`

```
List<CheckBox > allCheckBox = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

And when you create any `CheckBox`, you need to add it to your `List`

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
...
allCheckBox.add(cb);
```

After that you can access to the `CheckBox` by

```
allCheckBox.get(position).isChecked() == true
// allCheckBox.get(position) -> with return a CheckBox
// position is the index when you add checkbox to ArrayList, for example you have create 2 CheckBox dynamic
// then CheckBox1 is allCheckBox.get(0) and CheckBox2 is allCheckBox.get(1)
```

Comment: allCheckBox.get(position).isChecked() == true

Comment: where i have to put above cod?

Comment: @mrreza if you think my answer solve your problem, please mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like

```
cb.setId(anyPositiveInteger)
```

try this for more details [How can I assign an ID to a view programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically)