# How to get reference of radiobutton that is added dynamically in onclicklistener?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I do have a fragment inflating a layout that contains a single button.I added `radiogroup` and `radiobuttons` dynamically in `onCreateView()` method.But the problem is in `onclicklistener` of that button. While retrieving for `radiobutton` text that's checked in a `radioGroup` I do get `nulpointerexception`.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.variant_choose,null);

    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.apply_variant_button);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_for_radiobuttons_in_variants);

    final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup();
    rg.setId(View.generateViewId());
    rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    RadioButton rb[] = new RadioButton[5];
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){

            rb[j] = new RadioButton(getActivity());
            rb[j].setId(View.generateViewId());
            rb[j].setText(j);
            rg.addView(rb[j]);       

    }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

                String str1 = (String) rb1.getText();

        }
    });

  return v;
}
```

View v contains dynamically created `radiogroup` and button till `onCreateView`. But later in `onclicklistener` it's not the case.It only contains button that's defined in xml file? What could be the reason for this? How can I get the text of checked `radiobutton`?

Comment: You should work with Tags not with ids.

Comment: Might I point to this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically I think it can help you understand IDs a bit better and help you also discover some ways to implement them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't have a checked `RadioButton` in your `RadioGroup` therefore `rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` returns `-1`, then `findViewById` returns `null`.

Try something like `rb[0].setChecked(true);` after filling the array.

Comment: Yeah it could be a reason.But I checked a `radiobutton`. It works fine outside `onclicklistener`within its scope but no in `onClick `method