# How I can use a Fragment without a id in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment, android-framelayout

how can I find a fragment (framelayout) without id?

Here is my code:

```
private void setRect(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h){

        final Rect rect = new Rect(_x,_y,_w,_h);

        final PSPDFConfiguration configuration = new PSPDFConfiguration.Builder(BuildConfig.PSPDFKIT_LICENSE_KEY)
                .scrollDirection(PageScrollDirection.HORIZONTAL)
                .build();

        final Uri  assetFile = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/psp.pdf");

        final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(thisContext);

        runOnUiThread(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                frameLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());

                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;

                params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(rect.right-rect.left,rect.bottom-rect.top);
                params.leftMargin = rect.left;
                params.topMargin = rect.top;
                params.gravity = 0;

                frameLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

                viewer_one.setLayoutParams(params);
                viewer_one.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                viewer_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                thisActivity.addContentView(viewer_one,params);

                PSPDFFragment fragment;

                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                fragment = (PSPDFFragment) manager.findFragmentById(frameLayout.getId());

                if(fragment == null){
                    fragment = PSPDFFragment.newInstance(assetFile,configuration);

                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(frameLayout.getId(), fragment)
                            .commit();
                }

            }
        }));


    }
```

I don't use a framelayout in my layout xml.

**Update:**

I have update my code and get this error -> No view found for id 0x1 (unknown) for fragment PSPDFFragment{373f9470

Comment: `findFragmentByTag` ?

Comment: example? i dont know the tag :(

Comment: so you have no id, no tag, so what do you have? what do you need that anonymous fragment for?

Comment: i want to create all programmatically...i must :/

Comment: with a xml layout is it easy

Comment: post your code where you are adding PSPDFFragment fragment

Comment: you want to add PSPDFFragment in the framelayout ?

Comment: yes ...how this https://pspdfkit.com/guides/android/current/getting-started/using-fragment/

Comment: but i must create the fragment container programmatically

Comment: I make a update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Set an ID to a view programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically)

***Assign id via code (programmatically)***

Manually set ids using `someView.setId(int);`
The int must be positive, but is otherwise arbitrary- it can be whatever you want (keep reading if this is frightful.)
For example, if creating and numbering several views representing items, you could use their item number.

This should do it. Now you have an ID, use it for the fragment manager. Hope this helps.