# Get the text of a TextView by click?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout

I've created a method which adds a number of TextViews to a LinearLayout in a while loop. I'm having trouble identifying those TextViews by click. If I click on them, it prints out that they are the ID of my linear layout. Is there any way I can access them?

```
while(i.hasNext()){ 
        TextView x = new TextView(this);
        linearLayout.addView(x);
}
```

EDIT:
I understand this was an absurdly dumb question. 
This...

```
x.setOnClickListener(this);
```

...did the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I assign an ID to a view programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically)

Comment: @Charuක That does't work for my circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you will get the reference of clicked view in `OnClickListener()` callback. type cast that view into `textview` and call `getText()` method of `textview`.
Here is sample code:

```
while(i.hasNext()) { 
  TextView x = new TextView(this);       
  linearLayout.addView(x);
    x.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) v;
                v.getText();
            }

    });
}
```

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't think of that LOL! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you'd be using a for loop you could do something like this `x.setId(i+30);` any number in place of 30. In while you can still take a variable i and do something like `x.setId(x++ +30);` . now if you want to access them from a loop its simple `findViewById(i+30);` or else `findViewById(31);`