# Assign ID to added EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hy, I wanna ask something about dynamic `EditText` that's added by button click.

I have another scanner `Button` to scan qr code, get the value and set the value in each `EditText` added. To set the text I sure need to know the id of each `EditText`. So how do I assign id to each `EditText` or there's another way to work around with it.

Inside my add-button `onclick`

```
public void addView(View view){

    LinearLayout li = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.etMsisdn);
        edt = new EditText(this);
        edt.setId(0);
        li.addView(edt);
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: This post may help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Hope to helpful

```
String strname = "task" + Integer.toString(i);   
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editTextsMap.put(strname, editText);
```

Comment: Map<String, EditText> map, and then call

Answer (score 0):

You can set a tag for your dynamically created EditText with calling setTag(Object tag) method. Then, you can simply find it with calling findViewWithTag() method.

```
// Dynamically create EditText
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setTag("editText");

// Find it via tag
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewWithTag("editText");
```