# How to assign unique ids to dynamically created Views?

Tags: java, android, xml

In my app I am creating `Views` - in this case an `EditText` - dynamically. But every `View` I add needs to have a unique id.

```
EditText editText = new EditText(context);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
editText.setLayoutParams(params);

// Which value am I supposed to use here?
editText.setId(value);

layout.addView(editText);
```

I am afraid of conflicts if I assign a random value and I cannot think of any way to generate ids without the possibility of conflicts.

Please not that I know that one can define a fixed set of ids in res/values/ids.xml, but that is not what I want! I need to create the ids dynamically! I have no idea how many I need.

So is there any safe way to generate ids?

Comment: +1,see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937380/how-to-set-id-of-dynamic-created-layout similar to your issue.

Comment: @nobalG i wanted a method besides the one which uses id.xml file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Assign `id` via code (programmatically)

- Manually set `id`s using `someView.setId(`int`);`
- The `int` must be positive, but is otherwise arbitrary- it can be whatever you want (keep reading if this is frightful.)
- *For example, if creating and numbering several views representing items, you could use their item number.*

### Normally we do:

***To assign id -***

```
for(int i =0 ; i < yourIDcount ; i++){
    yourView.setId(i);
}
```

***To get id -***

```
View.findViewById(yourView.getId());
```

**Also,**

`API 17` introduced `View.generateViewId()` which generates a unique ID.

***Check:***

[how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460680/how-can-i-assign-an-id-to-a-view-programmatically) and [android-assign-and-retrieve-ids-dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261190/android-assign-and-retrieve-ids-dynamically).

Comment: How does this make sense: `View.findViewById(yourView.getId());`? You would need to already have an instance of the `View` to call `findViewById()` in the first place.

Comment: @XaverKapeller - This isn't necessary. The `android.view.View` is in the android package and you can directly call `findViewById()` on it to get the view by its id. You can check - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: @VedPrakash `findViewById` is not a `static` method. You can't call `View.findViewById`. You need an object to call it.

Comment: I am talking about the `yourView.getId()`. You call `getId()` on the `View` instance you are trying to get so obviously you already have the instance and don't need to find it again.

Comment: @Apoorv - `findViewById` is the public final method that looks for a child view with the given id. If this view has the given id, it returns this view. Search for `View.findViewById()` in the developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: Yes exactly!! It is a `public final` method and not `public static final`. You need an object of `View` so if you try to call `View.findViewById` it won't even compile.

Comment: @XaverKapeller - When you are creating the view dynamically, you created its instance and then called `yourView.setId()` to set the id and `yourView.getId()` to get the id back. :)

Comment: I realise that, I am just saying, calling `findViewById()` is kinda useless if you already have the instance :)

Comment: @Apoorv - Correct. So my understanding is you have to have `View view` then `view.findViewById(someID)`. This is what is mentioned in the docs also.

Comment: Yes you have to use `view.findViewById(someID)` and not `View.findViewById(someID)`

Comment: @Apoorv - I have to say that this is general way of explaining :)

Comment: You can use `View.generateViewId()` for unique id

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple ways you can reliably generate ids for your `Views`. Some can be used to dynamically generate ids at runtime, others can be used to statically define a fixed number of ids. I will go over a few solutions in this answer.

---

### Statically creating a fixed number of ids

Create a new xml file in res/values called ids.xml and add  elements with the type id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="name" type="id" />     <!-- Creates the id R.id.name -->
    <item name="example" type="id" />  <!-- Creates the id R.id.example -->

</resources>
```

You can generate ids for other resources as well! Just change the type.

---

### Dynamically generating ids from API level 17+

With API level 17 a new method was added to the `View` class:

```
int id = View.generateViewId();
```

With it you can create as many ids as you need dynamically!

---

### Dynamically generating ids before API level 17

As @Apoorv suggested you can view the source code of `generateViewId()` [**here**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/android/view/View.java#View.0sNextGeneratedId). By copying the code we can use this method even before API level 17:

```
private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

public static int generateViewId() {
    for (; ; ) {
        final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();

        // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
        int newValue = result + 1;
        if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.

        if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Just include it in a helper class and you are all set!

Comment: thanks....but i want to know besides this, where i don't have to create pre-defined id because i don't know how many will be created..

Comment: I have added a solution to create the ids dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @XaverKapeller [generateViewID()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/android/view/View.java#View.generateViewId%28%29) shows how the method generates unique ids. Can it be used directly before API 17 seeing as how it doesn't require anything special? Just an `AtomicInteger`

Comment: @Apoorv Very nice, I already updated my answer. This solution is better than everything else I have seen, but I have to admit it's kinda funny that all this method does is glorified incrementing. It's just a better version of the for loop suggested everywhere else.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Yes i was wondering the same thing. I mean it does not cross reference anywhere that whether the updated number is an already existing id or not

Comment: @Apoorv I think it does not matter if there are duplicates. It's not really a good example, but think of a `ListView`, in every row the ids are the same, but it still works because you are only looking for `Views` in one row at a time. The same thing applies everywhere else. When you are generating ids this way you just have to know what you are doing.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Oh yes I think I got the idea. Something like it does not matter if other `Views` have the same id as long as there exists a `View` with the id you are looking for in the `ViewGroup` you are looking for it in.

Comment: @Apoorv Exactly. I tested it right now and it seems that if there are multiple `Views` with the same id, it picks the first one it encounters in other words it traverses the view hierarchy from top. So if you have a layout with a `TextView` and a `ListView` and you are looking for the `TextView` but there are other `TextViews` with the same id in the `ListView` then it would pick the first `TextView` outside of the `ListView` because it is higher up in the view hierarchy. It seems this whole thing is pretty safe when it comes to the ids.

Comment: @Apoorv This is how `findViewById()` is implemented in a `ViewGroup`: [**Link to source**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.findViewTraversal%28int%29). `findViewTraversal()` is called by `findViewById()` if the id does not match the id of the `ViewGroup`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I was just trying to the same thing.