# Android - How to add radio buttons to a radiogroup in another Activity? (programatically)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, radio-button, radio-group

I'm very new to programming with Android, so I'm making a simple text RPG to practice developing for the platform. The player has access to a menu, which shows their items as a group of Radio Buttons. That way one can be selected to Equip/sell/etc. The game is handled in a completely different Activity. I want a random event that can happen in the Game activity to be able to add a new custom Radio button to the Inventory Activity page. On my Inventory Activity page, I've written a simple method:

```
    public void addRadioButtons(){

        RadioGroup items=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.invItems);
        RadioButton newItem = new RadioButton(this);
        newItem.setText("New Rare Item");
        newItem.setId(idCounter);
        idCounter++;
        items.addView(newItem);
}
```

When the random drop event is calculated in the Game Event, it just does a object.addRadioButtons() method call. This force closes every time, no matter what I try. I've also tried pre-formatting the button before adding it, also to no avail. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the reason in idCounter value. In Android view id must be calculated according to certain rules. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts) for more detals.

Comment: I've tried many different things for the ID. The Android documentation says that the ID number is arbitrary, so I was just trying to make it a positive integer. I've also tried various methods to generate ID's for it. No matter which way I've done it, it tosses back a null pointer exception.

Comment: Null pointer??? That's quite simple! Just enter to function on debugger and inspect all objects. May be items cannot be found, or idCounter does not initialised?

Comment: I'm very sorry, like I said I've very new at this, but how exactly would I do that? I've tried to mess around with the debugging a whole lot, but it usually only confuses me more. Oh, and the idCounter variable is initialized right away in the beginning of the class.