# Click event of HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, onclick, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontalscrollview inside which i have a bunch of images. Now i need to detect the click event in case any of the image is clicked within it. In short, i need the index of the image placed inside the horizontalscrollview, which was clicked.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bgcolor" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image2" />
```

I tried playing around OnTouchListener event, but that was getting triggered even while scrolling. And the OnClickListener was not even getting triggered no matter wherever you click.

```
horizontalScrollView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Testing scrollview");
        }
    });
```

Is there a workaround to get the index of the clicked image present inside the horizontalscrollview? I guess it can be achieved via "Gallery" widget but that is deprecated in API16. Can anyone share an approach to accomplish this via HorizontalScrollView?

Answer (score 3):

Attach an `OnClickListener` to each of the `ImageView` widgets in the `HorizontalScrollView`. Based on the `View` passed into `onClick()`, you will know which `ImageView` was clicked.

Specifically:

- Add `android:onClick="heyMyImageGotClickedWhoHoo"` to each `ImageView` element in your layout.
- Implement a `public void heyMyImageGotClickedWhoHoo(View v)` method in the activity that is loading this layout. In the body, you can use `v.getId()` and compare it to the `ImageView` widget IDs (e.g., `R.id.imageview1`) to determine which got clicked.

Or, you can create dedicated methods for each `ImageView`, rather than route them all to one. In that case, each `android:onClick` attribute would have a different value (e.g., `omgTheFirstImageWasClicked`), with a matching method in the activity (e.g., `public void omgTheFirstImageWasClicked(View v)`).

Comment: Thanks @commonsware ! I shall try to check this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the number of ImageViews may vary in your case. Then I would suggest using a List of IDs to keep record of them. While inserting new ImageView to HorizontalScrollView, use setId method to add each ImageView a custom ID and then add this ID to your List.

```
int uniqueID = getNewID();
myImage.setId(uniqueID);
myIdList.add(uniqueID);
myScrollView.addView(myImage);
```

If the number of ImageViews is fixed, then you can of course use classic array:

```
int[] ids = {R.id.firstImage, R.id.secondImage};
```

Then your onClick method (you have to add it to each ImageView) will look like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    for(int i=0; i<ids.size(); i++) {
        if(v.getId() == ids.get(i)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Index "+(i+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: how to create valid IDs - [Android: View.setID(int id) programmatically - how to avoid ID conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts)

Comment: Thanks @daemontus for sharing this approach as well as in future the horizontalscrollview will have dynamic imageviews in my case.