# How do I go about setting up a user interface that involves tags?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tags, onclick, android-alertdialog

Here is what I am aiming for:
[image]

I am unsure if I am doing this correctly. There are probably better,more efficient, and cleaner ways to do it, but I need to know how.

This layout was designed in xml and inflated via an inflater. The produced view was then placed into an AlertDialog. Thus, this is seen as an AlertDialog by the user.

My concern is with the tags section at the bottom. I want this to work like how Tumblr tags work. Type a string, hit the button, and a button with that tag name will show up in the blank section below it.

Now, if you click on those buttons (with their respective tag names), they will disappear from the frame.

I have several concerns.

1. I have trouble implementing listeners. If the AddTag button creates more buttons in the (currently invisible, but present) LinearLayout, then what about the created buttons? How do those buttons implement onClick listeners that will remove themselves from the LinearLayout if they were created in some inner method defined from the AddTag button's onClick method?
2. I am afraid about having to declare some of these views as FINAL in order to reference them in button methods and inner classes. I am now stuck because of this.
3. Do I have to define my own layout for the tag buttons? You see, a LinearLayout displays things one after the other, yes? I want to try to recreate how some social networking sites do it. Fill the layout with buttons from top to bottom, left to right. If there is no room left in the current row, go to the next one and add the tag button there. It's basically a dynamic LinearLayout that has autowrapping.

If there are any better ways of implementing this, please let me know a general step by step of what to do. I have not learned Fragments yet, but I think it may be VERY applicable here. Also, should I be creating a class that extends ViewGroup, inflating the XML there, and adding helper methods to handle things? I suppose from a DialogFragment I could then addView(the class I just created) and work from there?

Here is my current code by the way. I am stuck and stumped.

```
/**
    * Opens a view for the user to define their new action and add it to the
    * dictionary.
    * 
    * @param view
    */
   public void defineNewAction(View view) {
      final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
      View viewToSet = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.define_new_action_window_layout,
            null);      

      final EditText newActionName = (EditText) viewToSet
            .findViewById(R.id.set_action_name);

      final RadioGroup priorityGroup = (RadioGroup) viewToSet
            .findViewById(R.id.radiogroup_set_priority);

      final EditText goalTimeHours = (EditText) viewToSet
            .findViewById(R.id.set_goal_time_hours);

      final EditText goalTimeMinutes = (EditText) viewToSet
            .findViewById(R.id.set_goal_time_minutes);

      final EditText addTagsInput = (EditText) viewToSet
            .findViewById(R.id.add_tags_input);
      Button addTagButton = (Button) viewToSet.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_tags);
      final ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

      final LinearLayout currentTagsLayout = (LinearLayout) viewToSet
            .findViewById(R.id.current_tags);
      addTagButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(View v) {
            String tag = addTagsInput.getText().toString();
            tags.add(tag);
            Button newTag = new Button(builder.getContext());
            int tagId = tag.hashCode();
            if (tagId < 0)
               tagId *= -1;
            newTag.setId(tagId);

            newTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                  Button toRemove = (Button) currentTagsLayout.findViewById(tagId);
                  currentTagsLayout.removeView(toRemove);
               }
            });

            currentTagsLayout.addView(newTag);
         }
      });

      builder.setTitle("Define your action.");
      builder.setView(viewToSet);
      builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            String name = newActionName.getText().toString();
            int priority = priorityGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int goalHours = Integer
                  .parseInt(goalTimeHours.getText().toString());
            int goalMinutes = Integer.parseInt(goalTimeMinutes.getText()
                  .toString());
         }

      });
      builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

               }
            });
      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialog.show();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have trouble implementing listeners

There's no trouble. For the functionality you are trying to achieve, you can keep adding buttons and setting `OnClickListeners` on them. You don't even need to give them an id, or track them in any way. The following code inside your `OnClickListener` will do:

```
newTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Use the View given to you
        currentTagsLayout.removeView(v);

    }
});
```

> I am afraid about having to declare some of these views as FINAL

This is how Java works. I haven't noticed any crippling effects of this. You can also declare your variables as global to not have to define them as final. But I don't see why declaring them as final is an issue. Could you provide an example where this is a problem?

> Do I have to define my own layout for the tag buttons?

This is something you will have to deal with yourself. It's a design decision. If you need auto-wrapping support, you can look at `Android Flow Layout`: [Link](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout). It's an extended LinearLayout that supports auto-wrap of its contents.

> I have not learned Fragments yet, but I think it may be VERY
>   applicable here

I don't see why they would be.

Note/Aside: Some kind of a check here would be better:

```
String tag = "";

if (!addTagsInput.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    tag = addTagsInput.getText().toString();
} else {
    // handle empty string
}
```

Comment: I am afraid that marking a variable as final will not allow me to modify it later during runtime. Eclipse tells me to set such variables to final so that inner classes and methods can use them. So I listen, but do so reluctantly, keeping an eye out for errors.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link to the Flow layout. It's exactly what I need. (I thought I'd have to implement from scratch!)

Comment: Question: Why is it okay not to give my spawned buttons an id? What if I want to refer to them later from some other Activity?

Comment: @TonyN.Tran Assigning an id to the buttons would be required if you were trying to access a certain button. For example: upon checking a conditional, you need to change the text of a specific button. You'll need an id to to differentiate it from others. In case of an OnClickListener, the view that has been clicked is given to you as an argument. So, an id is not required.

Comment: @TonyN.Tran I think it'll be a good exercise for you to attempt replicating the Flow layout's functionality. You'll learn a lot in the process.

Comment: @user255882 If I were to assign ids dynamically, what would be the best way to do it? They have to be unique, right? Is my idea of using hashcode good, or should I try something different?

And I think I'll give a shot at making my own flow layout. :)

Comment: @TonyN.Tran `I am afraid that marking a variable as final will not allow me to modify it later during runtime`: Whether this will be a problem or not will depend on what you mean by `modify`. If you mean setting/changing properties using methods such as `setText()` or `setTextSize()`, then no. It won't be a problem because marking an object as final locks the object, not its properties.

Comment: @user255882 What do you mean by locking the object?
Final Object myObject = new Object();
myObject can still be modified via its methods, but myObject cannot be changed out for myOtherObject or null, right?

Comment: @TonyN.Tran This thread has a lot of information on how to assign unique view ids: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts). About `final`: your interpretation is correct. Basically, `final` makes sure that `myObject` cannot be assigned to any other instance of `MyObject`. But, `myObject` CAN be mutated: its fields can be changed. By `locking`, I meant that the pointer `myObject` is locked. It cannot be updated to point to another MyObject. Hope its clear now?

Comment: Indeed it is. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Actually, do you think you can help me with one more thing? After the user has created their new action, and clicks okay(onPositive button), it returns them back to the previous AlertDialog view. The previous dialog displays all the actions in a ListView. How would I update this view to display the newly created action? Is there some kind of startActivityForResult equivalent for AlertDialogs?

Comment: @TonyN.Tran let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37134/discussion-between-user2558882-and-tony-n-tran)