# Android 'Couldn't expand remoteViews for...' when creating layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications, android-linearlayout, remoteview

I'm trying to build my own layout programmatically then 'building' `RemoteViews` and show it as a notification.

Skeleton :

```
LinearLayout baseLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
for (X) {
    LinearLayout innerLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        for (Y) {
            TextView textV = new TextView(context);
        }
        innerLayout.addView(textV);
    }
    baseLayout.addView(innerLayout);
}
RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(getPcakageName(), baseLayout.getId());
```

For each Layout I set `LayoutParams`, `orientation` and `ID` from the method presented here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15442898/1405268.

When I try to start the notification with the `RemoteViews`, I get `Bad notification posted from package XXX: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for StatusBarNotification...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to build my own layout programmatically then 'building' RemoteViews and show it as a notification

The ID passed to the `RemoteViews` constructor needs to be a layout resource ID. You then need to use methods on `RemoteViews` to attempt to build your structure, though I am dubious that it will work.

Comment: Why would it be OK to give `ResourceID` and not generated unique ID ?

Comment: @SagiLow: First, the two are not related. Second, the documentation says that you need to supply a layout resource ID. Third, the point behind `RemoteViews` is to send a UI definition to some other process, and that process does not have access to your Java objects (e.g., `LinearLayout`).