# How to add a Fragment to a View without id?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-resources

I want to replace a `ListView` item with a `Fragment` when certain conditions are met, but the `View`, inside which I want to add it has no id (i.e. view's `getId()` returns `0xffffffff`)

```
View view = lv.getChildAt(pos);
FragmentManager fm = ((PagerAdapter)getAdapter()).getItem(getCurrentItem()).getChildFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().add(view.getId(), new AddPlaylistItemFragment()).commit();
```

`view` is a `LinearLayout` if it helps.

Any ideas on how to solve this

`E/AndroidRuntime(1731): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff`

error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give them an ID. Or a tag.
The view is coming from your listview, you put it in there. Probably using an adapter's getView. There where you create the view, give it an ID or a tag.

This one might be interesting [Android: View.setID(int id) programmatically - how to avoid ID conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1714297/2001247)