# How to find a button created dynamically? ANDROID

Tags: android, button, dynamic, find

I have created some buttons dynamically in a class with this code:
The variable drawView.getNumeroMallas() could be different each time

```
     for(int i=0;i<drawView.getNumeroMallas();i++){

                Button buttonMalla = new Button(this);
                buttonMalla.setText("Malla "+(i+1));
            buttonMalla.setId(i+1);
                buttonMalla.setTag(Boolean.FALSE);
}
```

And now I want to find these buttons inside a loop in another class. Any idea?

Comment: send the button to the other class, the id's are not stored like they would be is you create the id in your xml

Comment: How can I send a button to other class?

Comment: create a public method in the class and give it

Answer (score 0):

1. You can store them in the list and then access this list from another part of the code with the getter method.
2. you should not use `setId()` like this, because your ids can, actually, collide with another ones, so you should use `View.generateViewId()`.

Comment: `View.generateViewId()` is only available in SDK 17 and up do you still have to use that

Comment: @tyczj No, and I wouldn't use it in that case. I would recommend using the key generation method listed in this solution by phantomlimb:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts

Comment: @zgc7009 sorry that wasnt a question, there was a typo. `do you still have to use that` was suppose to be `so you still have to use that`