# Adding Fragments to LinearLayout, result NOT in right ORDER

Tags: android, layout, android-fragments

This is really strange issue, I was scratching my head before posting this.

Straight to the problem: I have a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` in my activity and I use the `FragmentManager` to pump my Fragments into the layout, each one has its unique Tag and UI, and the code works great.

```
...
for(object o: my_data)
{
    MyFragment f = MyFragment.newInstance(o.blah());
    Log.w("app","adding object "+o.tag_name()+"to the list");
    transaction.add(R.id.my_linear_layout_id, f, o.tag_name());
}
transaction.commit();
```

Say I have 3 objects with tag "1","2","3" in my_data. The result of above codes will display my Fragments in right order 1,2,3. In my UI they are 1,2,3 from top of the LinearLayout to bottom. like

**1
2
3**

Strange issue comes when I try to remove all Fragments and add them with the same code again.(Like refresh)

```
...
ft = frag_manager.beginTransaction();
for(object o: my_data)
{
    ft.remove(frag_manager.findFragmentbyTag(o.tag_name()));    
}
ft.commit();
```

The result would become reversed on my LinearLayout, from top to bottom:

**3
2
1**

Although my Log shows that 1,2,3 has been added to the layout, respectively.

I tried and test the code many times and found that the result is always correct at the FIRST time, but after any remove-all operation, the new result will be reversed and there will be no longer correct result. What could be the reason behind this issue? What am I missing? It's crazy imo.

Comment: What kind of Collection is your 'my_data'?

Comment: It's a ``LinkedList``, the above code is straightforward so I just use pesudo code.

Comment: I would not expect putting multiple fragments into a `LinearLayout` to be reliable, particularly across configuration changes, when you are no longer the one who is in charge of the order of addition of the fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operations order on one single FragmentTransaction are not allways respected.

You should try creating news FragmentTransacion in every operation and commit them in you desired order.
[Related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504790/android-multiple-fragment-transaction-ordering)

Comment: Well, it works. You save my life, thank you! I've to admit that I did a really serious search on SO to prevent a duplicate for my issue, and failed to find it. And it turned out to be a duplicate lol.