# ListView + ViewPager Resource not found exception on onResume event

Tags: android, android-listview, crash, android-viewpager, android-logcat

I have a frustrating issue in my application:

- I have a **Fragment** which contains one **ListView**.
- Every row of **ListView** loads a **ViewPager** and **ViewPagerCustomIndicator** objects from XML file.
- For each **ViewPager** loaded I set an Id **by viewHolder.viewPager.setId(Utils.generateViewId());**; I find this tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts).
- The **ListView** data is load on **onResume Fragment** event.

At **first** time, everything works **fine**. At **second** load, the **App crash** with this log:

> 08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633): Process:
>   com.playyoo.android.sportyes, PID: 31633 08-26 15:39:05.441:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31633):
>   **> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find
>   resource ID #0x1 08-26 15:39:05.441:** E/AndroidRuntime(31633):   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:1773)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:934)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1901)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1518)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:962)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:764)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1533) 08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManager.java:489)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:450)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 08-26
>   15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 08-26
>   15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 08-26 15:39:05.441:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 08-26
>   15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 08-26 15:39:05.441:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   08-26 15:39:05.441: E/AndroidRuntime(31633):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)

Ok the error is **obvious**, but I can't find the solution to fix it. Without **ViewPager** the application works fine.

This is my Adapter (*in this example I don't use Android recycling-cell mechanism*):

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        XmlEvento e = (XmlEvento) getItem(position);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        View view = _mInflater.inflate(_graphicResource, null);
        viewHolder.viewPager = (ViewPager) view
                .findViewById(R.id.live_view_pager);
        viewHolder.viewPagerIndicator = (ViewPagerIndicator) view
                .findViewById(R.id.live_view_pager_indicator);
        // viewHolder.viewPager.setId(position + 1);
        viewHolder.viewPager.setId(Utils.generateViewId());

        view.setTag(viewHolder);

        final List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

        for (int i = 0; i < scommesse.size(); i++) {

            XmlScommesse scommmessa = scommesse.get(i);

            Fragment fr = Live_Level_1_BetRow_Fragment.newInstance(e,
                    scommmessa);
            fragments.add(fr);
        }

            final String eId = getEventId(e);
            final Live_Bet_Level_1_Adapter mPagerAdapter = new Live_Bet_Level_1_Adapter(
                    _fragmentManager, fragments, _iBet);

            viewHolder.viewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
            viewHolder.viewPager.setCurrentItem(_viewPagerStoredPosition
                    .get(eId));

                // Bind the circle indicator to the adapter.
                viewHolder.viewPagerIndicator
                        .setViewPager(viewHolder.viewPager);
                viewHolder.viewPagerIndicator
                        .setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onPageSelected(int p) {

                                Live_Level_1_BetRow_Fragment fr = (Live_Level_1_BetRow_Fragment) fragments
                                        .get(p);
                                fr.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPageScrolled(int position,
                                    float positionOffset,
                                    int positionOffsetPixels) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }
                        });
```

The **Live_Level_1_BetRow_Fragment.newInstance(e,
                        bet);** si a simple **Fragment**, which contains:

> view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MY_ROW_LAYOUT, container, false);

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: How did you solve this ?