# How to generate Id for dynamically Generated TextView in Android?

Tags: android

When I dynamically generated a View, like textView, how can I automatically generate an Id for this textView? I know I can use the method setId, but I'm afraid that this Id i manually set would possibly conflict with some other Views' Id. Just in case!
When I set the layout parameters in relative layout, the id for all views seems necessary.
Is there any method i can use to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: the question is do you really need the view id?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1714297/2191256

Comment: I think your answer is here.... [adding TextViews programmatically][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts

Comment: See this soluction http://stackoverflow.com/a/15442898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to set id:

int count =0;

your_tv.setId(count);

to retrieve from that id:

your_tv.getId();

// here count can be any positive integer, it won't conflict with other view's ids.

Comment: Thanks. I found android automatically generated an id for me. No need to worry.

Comment: ok nice, but above method is for generating your own id and to use it as your own wish like as a count of anything.

Answer (score 0):

First ask yourself if the id is really necessary, if it is and you are worrying about possible conflicts there are previous questions similar to yours.

Take a look: 
[Android: View.setID(int id) programmatically - how to avoid ID conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714297/android-view-setidint-id-programmatically-how-to-avoid-id-conflicts)

Comment: Thanks. I suddenly found my worry unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method your_view.generateViewId() from API 17 which will give you an id unique for your view.